# Generating functions for finding the coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am new to the field of combinatorics and I recently came across a problem where it was asked to find the number of integer solutions to ${c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4=20  }$ where ${c_i\ge 0}$ for all ${1\le i\le4}$ with ${c_2}$ and ${c_3}$ being even integers.

Using the generating function, we know that the solution would be the coefficient of ${x^{20}}$ in the expansion of ${(1 +x+x^2+x^3+...)^2*(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+...)^2}$ which is equivalent to: ${(1-x)^{-2}*(1-x^2)^{-2}}$

Now, we know that the first part could be solved by computing:${(-1)^{20}\dbinom{-2}{20} = \dbinom{2+20-1}{20}=21}$

Since we know that:  ${(1+x^m)^n = \dbinom{n}{0} + \dbinom{n}{1}x^m + \dbinom{n}{2}x^{2m}+...+\dbinom{n}{n}x^{nm}}$

Would it be correct to assume that the coefficient of ${x^{20}}$ in ${{(1-x^2)^{-2}}}$ would be:  ${\dbinom{-2}{10}}$

Comment: The coefficients of product are not the products of coefficients! But the coefficients of a sum are the sums of coefficients. Thus, you should expand your rational function into simple fractions. And only then you compute the coefficients

Comment: coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $(1-x)^{-2}*(1-x^2)^{-2}$ is coefficient of ($x^{20}$ in $(1-x)^{-2}$ times coefficient of $x^0$ in $(1-x^2)^{-2}$) plus (coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $(1-x)^{-2}$ times coefficient of $x^2$ in $(1-x^2)^{-2}$)   plus (coefficient of $x^{16}$ in $(1-x)^{-2}$ times coefficient of $x^4$ in $(1-x^2)^{-2}$)  plus coefficient of $x^{14}$ in $(1-x)^{-2}$ times coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1-x^2)^{-2}$ and so on.

Comment: @Submathematics, this is true, but the expression you get with partial fraction expansion is more "closed form" than this one.

Comment: @zhoraster, you are right. But in this case even the partial fraction split would have six terms.

Comment: @Submathematics, which means that one would get a formula with six terms. Expanding the product, one gets a formula with $\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor$ terms. And $6<\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor$ for all but finite values of $n$.

Comment: @zhoraster, correct me if I am wrong but since we know that:  ${(1+x^m)^n = \dbinom{n}{0} + \dbinom{n}{1}x^m + \dbinom{n}{2}x^{2m}+...+\dbinom{n}{n}x^{nm}}$

Would it be correct to assume that the coefficient of ${x^{20}}$ in ${{(1-x^2)^{-2}}}$ would be:  ${\dbinom{-2}{10}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $(1-x^2)^{-2}$ is the coefficient of $y^{10}$ in $(1-y)^{-2}$ which is $(-1)^{10}\binom{-2}{10}=\binom{-2}{10}$.

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647),
$$
\binom{-2}{10}=(-1)^{10}\binom{11}{10}=11
$$

---

**Computation of the Coefficients**
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x)^{-2}(1-x^2)^{-2}
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{-2}{j}x^j\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-2}{k}x^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor}(-1)^{j-k}\binom{-2}{j-2k}\binom{-2}{k}x^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor}\binom{j-2k+1}{j-2k}\binom{k+1}{k}x^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor}(j-2k+1)(k+1)x^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left[(j+1)\binom{\lfloor j/2\rfloor+2}{2}-4\binom{\lfloor j/2\rfloor+2}{3}\right]x^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{j+3}{48}\left[\left(2j^2+12j+13\right)+(-1)^j3\right]x^j
\end{align}
$$
using the fact that $\lfloor j/2\rfloor=\frac{2j-1+(-1)^j}4$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: +1 for your carefully formulated and instructive answer.

Comment: Strictly in terms of binomial coefficient terms, would it be correct to assume the the final answer to this question would be:  ${(-1)^{20}\dbinom{-2}{20}*(-1)^{10}\dbinom{-2}{10}}$

Comment: @O.A.: If you plug $j=20$ into my answer you don't get $231$, so I don't think it would be correct to assume that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer with a slightly different approach. We use the  the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^t]$ to denote the coefficient $a_t$ of $x^t$ in a series $A(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^j$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^t]&(1-x^2)^{-2}(1-x)^{-2}\\
> &=[x^t]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{k}(-x^2)^k\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{j}(-x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^t]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+1}{k}x^{2k}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{j+1}{j}x^j\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^t]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^{2k}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)x^j\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor t/2\right\rfloor}(k+1)[x^{t-2k}]\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+1)x^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor t/2\right\rfloor}(k+1)(t-2k+1)\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor t/2\right\rfloor+1}\left((t+3)k-2k^2\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{6}\left(\left\lfloor t/2\right\rfloor+1\right)\left(\left\lfloor t/2\right\rfloor+2\right)
> \left(3t-4\left\lfloor t/2\right\rfloor+3\right)\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (1) we use the series expansion of the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
- In (2) we use the identity $\binom{r}{s}=\binom{-r+s-1}{s}(-1)^s$
- In (3) we use the linearity of the coefficient of operator and the identity $[x^t]x^uA(x)=[x^{t-u}]A(x)$. We also set the upper index of the first sum to $\left\lfloor t/2\right\rfloor$, since the exponent of $x^{t-2k}$ has to be non-negative.
- In (4) we set $j=t-2k$ in order to select the proper coefficient of $x^{t-2k}$.
- In (5) we shift the index by one for simplification only and rearrange the summands according to increasing powers of $k$.
- In (6) we use the summation formula $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

> Since we need the coefficient of $x^{20}$ we obtain from (6)
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^{20}](1-x^2)^{-2}(1-x)^{-2}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot11\cdot12\cdot23=405
> \end{align*}

Note, that we do not multiply  the series representation of  $(1-x^2)^{-2}$ and $(1-x)^{-2}$ using Cauchy multiplication. We walk instead with the coefficient of operator through the series.