# Let $\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)=\binom{n+k-1}k$, prove $\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)=\sum_{i=0}^k\ \left(\!\!{n-1\choose i}\!\!\right)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, factorial, inclusion-exclusion

I need help proving this.
Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers,
and let
$$\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)
={n+k -1\choose k},$$
prove:

$$\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\ \left(\!\!{n-1\choose i}\!\!\right).$$

I'm thinking I need to show that the equation $$\sum_{i=0}^{k}\ \left(\!\!{n-1\choose i}\!\!\right) = {n+k -1\choose k}$$ is true but I am unsure how to make this jump.

Comment: Neither of those identities is true. Let $n=3, k=2$; then the LHS of the first one is $3$, the RHS is $4$; the LHS of the second one is $4$, the RHS of the second one is $6$.

Comment: Unless the double-bracket is a notation I'm not familiar with?

Comment: What is $\left(\binom{n}{k}\right)$?

Comment: The notation in question is multi choose. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: @martycohen  The notation is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets).

Comment: I just provided [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1552888/12042) to a later instance of the same question. (I was working back through the latest questions, so I encountered the other one first.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi choose proof problem: $ \left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\ \left(\!\!{n-1\choose i}\!\!\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552058/multi-choose-proof-problem-left-n-choose-k-right-sum-i-0k)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^k\left(\!\!\binom{n-1}{i}\!\!\right)
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n+i-2}{i}\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i\binom{1-n}{i}\tag{1b}\\
&=(-1)^k\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{-1}{k-i}\binom{1-n}{i}\tag{1c}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{-n}{k}\tag{1d}\\[3pt]
&=\binom{n+k-1}{k}\tag{1e}\\[3pt]
&=\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ definition
$\text{(1b):}$ [negative binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$\text{(1c):}$ $(-1)^k\binom{-1}{k-i}=(-1)^k(-1)^{k-i}[k\ge i]=(-1)^i[i\le k]$
$\text{(1d):}$ [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$\text{(1e):}$ negative binomial coefficient
$\text{(1f):}$ definition

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

[image]

I encourage the reader to find out how...

Here's a combinatorial proof.

1. Let’s say there is a $2$-D plane where we have demarcated $k+n$ number of points.
2. We want to form as many clusters of $n+1$ points as possible.
3. Clearly, there’s going to be $\displaystyle \binom{k+n}{n+1}$ clusters.
4. Now, we need to dive into the world of every individual point.

   1. The first point has to choose $n$ points from remaining $k+n-1$ , that makes $\displaystyle \binom{k+n-1}{n}$ clusters
   2. The second point will have to choose $n$ points from remaining $k+n-2$ points. (Because we are not dealing with the first one again.) That makes $\displaystyle \binom{k+n-2}{n}$ clusters.
   3. And this goes on till the last point has exactly $n$ points remaining to choose from. Hence$\displaystyle \binom{n}{n}$ cluster(s).
5. Thus in total we have these many ways:
   $\displaystyle \binom{k+n-1}{n} +\binom{k+n-2}{n} +\binom{k+n-3}{n} +\ldots +\binom{n}{n}\tag*{}$
   Flipping the series in (5) and equating with (3):
   $\displaystyle \binom{n}{n} +\binom{n+1}{n} +\binom{n+2}{n} +\ldots +\binom{n+k-1}{n} =\binom{n+k}{n+1}\tag*{}  $
   $\displaystyle \text{or, }\sum _{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{n+i}{n} =\binom{n+k}{n+1}\tag*{} $
   $\displaystyle \text{i.e., }\boxed{\sum _{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{n+i}{i} =\binom{n+k}{k-1}}\tag*{} $

Take $k=k'+1$ and $n=n'-2$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorial Proof: Suppose we have n objects in set $S = \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.

LHS: $\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)$ is the number of $k$-subsets from $S$ with repeats (by definition of multichoose).

RHS: We consider the number of occurrences of $n$ in a k-subset of $S$.

- If $n$ is not in the subset, we have $\left(\!\!\binom{n-1}{k}\!\!\right)$ such subsets since we create a $k$-subset from all objects except $n$.
- If $n$ is in the subset once, we have $\left(\!\!\binom{n-1}{k-1}\!\!\right)$ such subsets since we have $k-1$ spots remaining in the subset.
- If $n$ is in the subset twice, we have $\left(\!\!\binom{n-1}{k-2}\!\!\right)$ such subsets.

  $\vdots$
- If $n$ is in the subset $n$ times, we have $\left(\!\!\binom{n-1}{0}\!\!\right) = 1$ such subsets since no spots remain.

Thus, $\sum_{i=0}^k \left(\!\!\binom{n-1}{i}\!\!\right)$ represents all such cases when $n$ is in the k-subset $0, 1, 2, \cdots, n$ times.