# How many different dozens of cupcakes are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem**

> Caleb's Cupcakes sells red velvet, vanilla cream and chocolate chip cupcakes. How many different combinations are possible for a dozen cupcakes at Caleb's?

I solved it by a distribution and finding all nonnegative solutions to $x+y+z = 12$. What is wrong with this method?

Comment: How did you come up with that expression?

Comment: Why is there something wrong with that method?

Comment: Because the answer is $91$ in the book but this answer gives me $78$ (13 choose 2).

Comment: Either your formula or your computation is incorrect, for this is a correct method, you should get $\binom{3+12-1}{12} = 91$

Comment: The number of non negative solutions to $x_1+\cdots+x_n = k$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$. Here $n=12, k=3$.

Comment: Oh you are correct. Sorry I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 1):

**Stars and Bars**

There are several approaches. One is the [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) approach. This approach arranges $12$ stars and $2$ bars:
$$
\overbrace{\star\star\star}^{\text{red velvet}}\mid\overbrace{\star\star\star\star\star}^{\text{vanilla cream}}\mid\overbrace{\star\star\star\star}^{\text{chocolate chip}}
$$
Counting all possible arrangements of the stars and bars give all possible combinations of the types of cupcakes; i.e. $\binom{14}{2}=91$.

---

**Generating Function**

We can also develop the generating function of the number of combinations of $n$ cupcakes. Consider the product
$$
\begin{align}
&\overbrace{(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)}^{\text{red velvet}}\overbrace{(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)}^{\text{vanilla cream}}\overbrace{(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)}^{\text{chocolate chip}}\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{(1-x)^3}\\[3pt]
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-3}{n}(-x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+2}{n}x^n\\
\end{align}
$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of non-negative solutions to $a+b+c=n$, where $x^a$ is taken from the red velvet sum, $x^b$ is taken from the vanilla cream sum, and $x^c$ is taken from the chocolate chip sum. To see why $(-1)^n\binom{-3}{n}=\binom{n+2}{n}$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647).

Setting $n=12$, we get $\binom{14}{12}=91$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you correctly apply stars and bars, you get $\binom{12+3-1}{3-1} = 91$

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is ${n+r-1\choose r-1}$ so plugging in $n=12,r=3$ we get $91$ so theres nothing wrong in your method only your application is wrong.