# Expectation of the number of times a coin is thrown until the appearance of a second "tail"

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

$X$ is the random variable that signifies the number of times a coin is thrown such until the appearance of a second "tail". With the probability of an appearance of "tails" on one toss being $p$. Find this expectation.

I know that

$$P\{X=k\}=\binom{k-1}{1}p^2(1-p)^{k-2}$$

I just do not know how to calculate the expectation for this.

Comment: See [negative binomial distribtuion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). You need an average of $1/p$ tosses to get a tail, so you need $2/p$ of them to get $2$ tails.

Comment: @A.S.: this simply follows from the linearity of expectation. It's a nice approach. Consider writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your expression for $\Pr(X=k)$ we have
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)p^2(1-p)^{k-2}.$$
Let 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots.$$ Take second derivatives. We get
$$f''(x)=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}.$$
Let $x=1-p$ and multiply the result by $p^2$.

**Remark:** If you already know the mean of the geometric distribution, here is a simple way. Let $U$ be the number of tosses until the first tail, and let $V$ be the number of tosses between the first tail and the second. Then $X=U+V$, where $U$ and $V$ have geometric distribution. The mean of each of $U$ and $V$ is $\frac{1}{p}$, so the mean of $X$ is $\frac{2}{p}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since André has given the complete answer, I will finish mine. This relates to the comment by A.S.

The expectation would be
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty k\binom{k-1}{1}p^2(1-p)^{k-2}
&=2p^2\sum_{k=2}^\infty\binom{k}{2}(1-p)^{k-2}\\
&=2p^2\sum_{k=2}^\infty\binom{k}{k-2}(1-p)^{k-2}\\
&=2p^2\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^{k-2}\binom{-3}{k-2}(1-p)^{k-2}\\
&=2p^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-3}{k}(1-p)^k\\
&=2p^2\frac1{(1-(1-p))^3}\\
&=\frac2p
\end{align}
$$
where $\binom{-3}{k-2}$ is a [negative binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647).

Comment: I honestly want you to have the answer too, but the other answer is just as good and done quicker. I hope you can understand. I appreciate your effort very much. :)

Comment: The point of my comments is that without showing any of the work you attempted, you are essentially asking us to do your homework for you. This is why I delayed posting the complete solution. Since André already did your homework for you, it seemed pointless not to show an alternate approach.

Comment: It's actually not homework in question.

Comment: Well, we have no way to know this. It appears so, but this is why this has been abstracted to the idea of wanting [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Context helps us to know where you are having problems and allows us to address this. It also works to prevent people getting their homework done for them.

Comment: Thanks, in the future I will take into consideration to give more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu_{n}$ denote the expectation of the number of times a coin
is thrown until the appearance of an $n$-th tail.

Then you are looking for $\mu_{2}$.

Let $E$ denote the event that the first throw is a tail.

Then $\mu_0=0$ and $\mu_{n}=\left(1+\mu_{n-1}\right)P\left(E\right)+\left(1+\mu_{n}\right)P\left(E^{c}\right)$ for $n>0$, so that:

$\mu_{1}=1P\left(E\right)+\left(1+\mu_{1}\right)P\left(E^{c}\right)=1+\mu_{1}\left(1-p\right)$
implying that $\mu_{1}=\frac{1}{p}$.

and:

$\mu_{2}=\left(1+\mu_{1}\right)P\left(E\right)+\left(1+\mu_{2}\right)P\left(E^{c}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)p+\left(1+\mu_{2}\right)\left(1-p\right)$
implying that $\mu_{2}=\frac{2}{p}$.

With induction it can be shown that $\mu_n=\frac{n}{p}$.