# How do we prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{r}x^n =\frac{x^r}{(1-x)^{r+1}}$ .

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

We know that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{r}x^r = (1+x)^n$ but how do we prove $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{r}x^n = \frac{x^r}{(1-x)^{r+1}}$?

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647) it is shown that
$$
\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}=(-1)^{n-r}\binom{-r-1}{n-r}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=r}^\infty\binom{n}{r}x^n
&=\sum_{n=r}^\infty(-1)^{n-r}\binom{-r-1}{n-r}x^n\\
&=x^r\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{-r-1}{n}x^n\\
&=\frac{x^r}{(1-x)^{r+1}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way is by induction on $r$. For $r=0$ it’s just

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=\frac1{1-x}\;.$$

If

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}rx^n=\frac{x^r}{(1-x)^{r+1}}\;,$$

then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}{r+1}x^n&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\binom{n-1}r+\binom{n-1}{r+1}\right)x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-1}rx^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-1}{r+1}x^n\\
&=x\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}rx^n+x\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}{r+1}x^n\\
&=\frac{x^{r+1}}{(1-x)^{r+1}}+x\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}{r+1}x^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$(1-x)\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}{r+1}x^n=\frac{x^{r+1}}{(1-x)^{r+1}}\;,$$

and

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}{r+1}x^n=\frac{x^{r+1}}{(1-x)^{r+2}}\;.$$