# power series with binomial coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, binomial-coefficients

Good evening,
I don't know how to find the function associate with this power series :
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k} x^n$$

Should I look for a differential equation ?

Thx in advance

Comment: Have you tried doing it for small values of $k?$

Comment: if k = 0 , $ f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would look for something of the form: $$\dfrac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$ While that may not be it exactly, it will probably be something close.

Comment: Good.  What about $k=1?$

Comment: if k = 1, $f(x) = \frac {x}{(1-x)^2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Series of binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}{\binom nk}x^n=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941603/series-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-limits-n-k-infty-binom-nkxn-frac)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!} x^{n-k}x^k \\[10pt]
={} & \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{d^k}{dx^k} x^n \\
& \text{Pulling out $x^k/k!$ works because $k$ does not change as $n$ changes.} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{x^k}{k!} \, \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \\
& \text{This works because power series can be differentiated} \\
& \text{term by term. Here we need not start at $k$ since the} \\
& \text{derivatives of the first $k-1$ terms are $0.$} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{x^k}{k!} \, \frac {d^k}{dx^k} \, \frac 1 {1-x} = \frac{x^k}{k!} \, k!(1-x)^{-(k+1)} = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}.
\end{align}

Comment: thank you, it's very clear