# Find sum of infinite series with binomial coefficient

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I find sum $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}$? I tried differentiating binomial, but it didn't really help :(

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1941603/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1933175/42969

Comment: I deleted my answer because this is a duplicate, and instead posted it as an answer to the original question. You’d asked why the probabilities sum to $1$. This is because the sum is over the probabilities for disjoint events, one of which will eventually occur at some point with probability $1$. The probability that you conduct an infinite sequence of Bernoulli trials with non-zero success probability and never get $k+1$ successes is $0$.

Comment: @MartinR: You can add a second original to the duplication notice. I think it would be worthwhile to add https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941603 because it has more different derivations (I added mine there as well). (I can’t do it because I don’t have the golden calculus badge. :-)

Comment: @joriki: Done...