# An alternating sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation

How to calculate this sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k{n \choose k} {3n-k-1 \choose 2n -k }
$$
without complex integral technique? Or how to calculate asymptotic nature this sum without calculation of this sum?

Comment: it looks like van der mondes idenity is involved

Comment: $  \left(-1\right)^{n + 1}{2n - 1 \choose n}\,,\qquad n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 7):

I like combinatorial solutions, and the form of the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}$$

immediately suggests that it could result from an [inclusion-exclusion calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement), though it is missing what would normally be the final term,

$$(-1)^n\binom{2n-1}n\;.$$

It turns out to be convenient to make use of the fact that

$$\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}=\binom{3n-k-1}{n-1}$$

to rewrite the summation as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{3n-k-1}{n-1}\;.$$

Suppose that I want to count the $(n-1)$-element subsets of $[3n-1]\setminus[n]$, where as usual $[m]=\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for any $m\in\Bbb Z^+$. For each $k\in[n]$ let $\mathscr{A}_k$ be the family of $(n-1)$-element subsets of $[3n-1]$ that do not contain $k$. It’s not hard to see that if $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]$, then

$$\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}\mathscr{A}_k\right|=\binom{3n-1-|I|}{n-1}\;,$$

so

$$\left|\bigcup_{k\in[n]}\mathscr{A}_k\right|=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}\mathscr{A}_k\right|=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k\binom{3n-1-k}{n-1}\;.$$

This is the number of $(n-1)$-element subsets $S$ of $[3n-1]$ such that $[n]\nsubseteq S$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{3n-1}{n-1}-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k\binom{3n-1-k}{n-1}&=\binom{3n-1}{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{3n-1-k}{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{3n-1-k}{n-1}
\end{align*}$$

is the number of $(n-1)$-element subsets $S$ of $[3n-1]$ such that $[n]\subseteq S$. This is obviously $0$, so

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{3n-1-k}{n-1}=0\;,$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{3n-1-k}{n-1}&=-(-1)^n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\binom{2n-1}n\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @BrianMScott: I appreciate your combinatorial experience and capabilities. To me it seems you don't have to look for a combinatorial answer, but you can  simply **read** the formulas in a combinatorial manner. :-)  (+1)

Comment: @Markus: In this case that’s very nearly true, though I do think that a *little* interpretation is required.

Comment: @BrianMScott: I agree and it's an appeasing message that you also need at least a *little* interpretation. Regards,

Answer (score 5):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
 \begin{align*}
 [z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
 \end{align*}

> We obtain for $n\geq 1$:
>   \begin{align*}
>  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}&(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}\\
>  &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{-n}{2n-k}-\binom{-n}{n}\tag{1}\\
>  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[z^k](1+z)^n[u^{2n-k}](1+u)^{-n}+\color{blue}{(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n}}\tag{2}\\
>  &=[u^{2n}](1+u)^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k[z^k](1+z)^n+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n}\tag{3}\\
>  &=[u^{2n}]1+(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n}\tag{4}\\
>  &=(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n}
>  \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^k$. We also add the term with index $k=n$ to the sum and subtract $\binom{-n}{n}$ accordingly.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and use again the binomial identity as in (1). We also set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.

  In fact we have isolated the result (blue) and show the rest is equal to zero.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule
  $$[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$$
- In (4) we use the substitution rule with $z:=u$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k u^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k [z^k]A(z)
  \end{align*}

  do some simplifications and observe the coefficient of $[u^{2n}]1=0$.

Comment: +1. The $\left[\cdots\right]$ hides the Complex Method, anyway. Fine answer.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Thanks for your nice comment! :-)

Answer (score 3):

$(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1-x)^n$.
$\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}=\binom{3n-k-1}{n-1}$ is the coefficient of $x^{2n-k}$ in
$$ \sum_{h\geq 0}\binom{n-1+h}{n-1}x^h = \frac{1}{(1-x)^n} $$
It follows that for any $n>0$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{3n-k-1}{n-1}=[x^{2n}]\frac{(1-x)^n}{(1-x)^n} = 0 $$
and:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{3n-k-1}{n-1}= \color{red}{-(-1)^{n}\binom{n}{n}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}}. $$
Asymptotics can be derived from $\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$

Comment: your generating functions approach yields a nice alternative to my "standard argument" (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Ok here we go:

$$
s(k,n)=(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}=
(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{-(-n)+ 2n-k-1}{2n-k}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{-n}{2n-k}
$$

[See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Furthermore in the form above it is clear that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{2n}s(k,n)=0 \quad \color{red}{(1)}
$$

by [Vandermonde's identiy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Furthermore 
$$s(k,n)=0 \quad \text{for} \quad  k>n  \quad \color{blue}{(2)} $$
by definition of the Binomial coefficent.

Combining $\color{red}{(1)}$ and $\color{blue}{(2)}$ yields

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}s(k,n)=-s(n,n) 
$$

or

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{n-1}s(k,n)=-\binom{-n}{n}
> $$

Comment: (+1) To deal with it as a convolution is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}
&=(-1)^{n+1}\binom{2n-1}{n}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{-n}{2n-k}\tag{1}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\binom{2n-1}{n}+\binom{0}{2n}\tag{2}\\[4pt]
&=(-1)^{n+1}\binom{2n-1}{n}+[n=0]\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: add and subtract the $k=n$ term
$\phantom{(1)\text{:}}$ use [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647) to get $(-1)^k\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}=\binom{-n}{2n-k}$
$(2)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(3)$: $\binom{0}{2n}=[n=0]$ using [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script to compute the first few values of the sequence:

$n$: $f(n)$

2: -3

3: 10

4: -35

5: 126

6: -462

7: 1716

8: -6435

9: 24310

10: -92378

11: 352716

12: -1352078

13: 5200300

14: -20058300

15: 77558760

16: -300540195

17: 1166803110

18: -4537567650

19: 17672631900

I inputted the first 10 of those values into the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=-3%2C+10%2C+-35%2C+126%2C+-462%2C+1716%2C+-6435%2C+24310%2C+-92378%2C+352716&language=english&go=Search) and found that your sum appears to be:

$$(-1)^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{3n-k-1}{2n-k}$$

The LHS below should be much easier to analyze asymptotically (use Stirling's approximation).  The two sequences match on at least the first 20 or so terms (all I checked).  You may want to prove (induction perhaps) that they are the same--unless you believe/are convinced enough that 20+ term match implies they are the same already.