# Number of non-negative integer solutions for $x+y+z = n^2$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, generating-functions

What is the number of solutions for $x+y+z = n^2$ for $x,y,z$ non-negative integers?

I thought to use generating functions. I know that the generating function for $x_1+x_2+...+x_k= n$ when $x_i \in S_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,...k\}$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\prod_{i=0}^{k}(\sum_{n\in S_i}x^n)  $$
based in that can I say that the generating function for the number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+...+x_k= n^2$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=(\prod_{i=0}^{k}(\sum_{n\in S_i}x^n))^2  $$

If not, is there a different way to find the number of solutions for the equation above?

**EDIT:**

I added another variable, so now the number of solutions for this equation, because I wanted to ask about the general case

Comment: Hint: for each $x\leq n^2$ there is exactly one matching $y$.

Comment: @Wojowu you are right of course, I meant to ask for the general case (for example with 3 variables)

Comment: You just have to look at the coefficient $a_{n^2}$ in the first generating function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordinary Generating Function for the number of solution :$ x_1 + x_2 + \cdot\cdot\cdot + x_k = n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526999/ordinary-generating-function-for-the-number-of-solution-x-1-x-2-cdot-cdo)

Comment: for $x,y, \mathbf {and z} $ non-negative integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with generating functions but here is a simpler way. You are searching for the number of weak compositions of $n^2$ into $k=3$ parts ($x$, $y$, and $z$). The answer is given by [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)):

$$
\binom{n^2 + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{n^2 + 2}{2}
$$