# Variance of flipping a coin until getting heads

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, geometric-distribution

Suppose we toss a fair coin. Let $N$ denote the number of tosses until we get heads. What is $Var(N)$?

> My approach to this question is to find compute $[^2]- E[N]^2$. I got $E[N] = 2$ since $N$ follows a geometric distribution but I am having trouble with finding $[^2]$. If we do the series expansion on the expected value of $N^2$ we will get $1\times0.5 + 4\times0.5^2 + 9\times0.5^3 + ... ,$ but I have no idea how to solve this series. Any tips would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I attempted to subtract $E[N^2]$ from $2E[N^2]$ but got another infinite sum I am not sure how to solve

> $2E[N^2] = 1 + 4\times0.5 + 9\times0.5^2 +...$
>
> $2E[N^2] - E[N^2] = 1 + 3(0.5) + 5(0.5^2) + 7(0.5^3)...$

Did I subtract the wrong terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Hint

Let $S = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^2 \, / \, 2^n$. What is $2S - S$?

See also [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864643/evaluating-frac1221-frac3222-frac5223-cdots-using-sigma/2864681#2864681) for a generalization of the above series.

## Full answer

Let's start by computing the first moment:
$$\mathbb{E}N=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{-n}.$$
A trick involving shifting the index of summation yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}N & =2\mathbb{E}N-\mathbb{E}N\\
 & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{-n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{-n}\\
 & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+1\right)2^{-n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{-n}\\
 & =1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\\
 & =2.
\end{align*}

Now, let's tackle the second moment:
$$\mathbb{E}N^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}2^{-n}.$$
The same trick yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}N^{2} & =2\mathbb{E}N^{2}-\mathbb{E}N^{2}\\
 & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}2^{-n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}2^{-n}\\
 & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n+1\right)^{2}2^{-n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2}2^{-n}\\
 & =1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(2n+1\right)2^{-n}\\
 & =1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{-n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\\
 & =1+2\mathbb{E}N+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\\
 & =1+4+1\\
 & =6.
\end{align*}

In conclusion,
$$\operatorname{Var}(N)=\mathbb{E}N^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}N\right)^{2}=6-4=2.$$

Comment: I'm revisiting this question and having some trouble. $2S = 1 + 0.5(4) + 0.5^2(9)...$
$2S-S = 1 + 3(0.5) + 5(0.5^2) + 7(0.5^3) +...$ this just seems to get me another infinite sequence with varying numerators

Comment: @Bob could you take a look at this?

Comment: @shrizzy: I updated it to include a full answer