# $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+k)!}{n! k!} x^n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-x)^{-k-1}$

Tags: summation

I am having trouble with proving following equalities

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+k)!}{n! k!} x^n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-x)^{-k-1}
\end{align}

How this equalities holds?

Comment: $\binom{n+k}{n}=(-1)^n\binom{-k-1}{n}$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647))

Comment: @robjohn, Oh there is a formula for combinatorics for negative case!, That was my first experience!. I learn binomial theorem for negative exponents because of you! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll begin by proving $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(n+k)!}{n!k!}x^n=(1-x)^{-k-1}$ by noting the binomial theorem gives the right-hand side's $x^m$ coefficient as $\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\prod_{j=1}^m(-k-j)$, which is exactly what we want. Applying $\sum_{k\ge0}$ gives the desired result. Note the convergence assumptions: in the first step we required $|x|<1$, while in the second we need $|1-x|>1$, in which case the result is $\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-x}}=-\frac{1}{x}$. For real $x$ both conditions hold iff $x\in(-1,\,0)$.