# Showing $\binom{2d-1}{n}-(n+1){d-1\choose n}=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n-i}{n+1\choose i+1}{id-d+n\choose n}$ for $n\geq1$ and $d\geq n+1$

Tags: combinatorics

Recently, when I was trying to compute Hodge numbers of hypersurfaces in toric varieties, I discovered the following combinatorial identity:

> For every positive integers $n\geq 1$ and $d\geq n+1$ the following is an identity
>    $$
>    \binom{2d-1}{n}-(n+1){d-1\choose n}=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{n-i}{n+1\choose i+1}{id-d+n\choose n}
>  $$

I tried to prove it by induction on $n$; for $n=1$ the identity becomes trivial, but the inductive step seems to be very hard (at least for me!).

For $d=n+1$ the identity can be proved by using arguments of V. Batyrev involving polar duality of reflexive polytopes. But for greater $d$ I have not any idea...

Someone can help me?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Note that $\dbinom{\left(i-1\right)d-d+n}{n}$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $i$. If you take its $n+1$-st finite difference, you thus get $0$. Hence, $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+1} \left(-1\right)^i \dbinom{n+1}{i} \dbinom{\left(i-1\right)d-d+n}{n} = 0$. Now, substitute $i+1$ for $i$ in this sum and you got the right hand side of your equality, up to sign and two addends. Bring the two addends on the left side.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Darij!!

Answer (score 3):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{1}
  \end{align*}

> We start     with the right-hand side and obtain for $d-1\geq n\geq 1$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{n-i}\binom{n+1}{i+1}\binom{id-d+n}{n}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-i}\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{id-2d+n}{n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}(-1)^{n+1-i}\binom{n+1}{i}[z^n](1+z)^{id-2d+n}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^n](1+z)^{n-2d}\left((1+z)^d-1\right)^{n+1}\\
> &\qquad-(-1)^{n+1}[z^n](1+z)^{n-2d}\left(1-(n+1)(1+z)^d\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^n[z^n](1+z)^{n-2d}-(-1)^n(n+1)(1+z)^{n-d}\tag{5}\\
> &=(-1)^n\binom{n-2d}{n}-(-1)^n(n+1)\binom{n-d}{n}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{2d-1}{n}-(n+1)\binom{d-1}{n}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we shift the index and start with $i=2$.
- In (3) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem and subtract the terms with $i=0$ and $i=1$ as compensation.
- In (5) we observe that $((1+z)^d-1)^{n+1}=\left(dz+\binom{d}{2}z^2+\cdots\right)^{n+1}$ is a polynomial in $z$ with powers greater than $n$. So, the coefficient of $z^n$ of the left-most term is zero.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $z^n$.
- In (7) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ twice.

Comment: Looks correct. Is there a factor of $(-1)^{n+1}$ missing at the front of line $(4)$?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks. I don't think the factor is missing.

Comment: Yes I see it now. (+1).

Comment: You might be interested in the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342361/).

Answer (score 2):

First note that as an order $n+1$ [repeated difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) of a degree $n$ polynomial,
$$
\overbrace{\sum_{i=-1}^n(-1)^{n-i}\binom{n+1}{i+1}}^\text{order $n+1$ difference}\overbrace{\binom{id-d+n}{n}\vphantom{\sum_{i=-1}^n}}^\text{degree $n$ polynomial}=0\tag1
$$
The difference between $(1)$ and the sum in the question are the $i=-1$ and $i=0$ terms. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{n-i}\binom{n+1}{i+1}\binom{id-d+n}{n}
&=\textstyle\overbrace{\color{#C00}{(-1)^n\binom{n+1}{0}\binom{-2d+n}{n}}}^{\text{negative of $i=-1$ term of $(1)$}}-\overbrace{\color{#090}{(-1)^n\binom{n+1}{1}\binom{-d+n}{n}}}^{\text{$i=0$ term of $(1)$}}\\[3pt]
&=\color{#C00}{\binom{2d-1}{n}}-\color{#090}{(n+1)\binom{d-1}{n}}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
where in the last step of $(2)$, we evaluated the [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647).

Comment: I see that the polynomial nature of this answer was mentioned in a comment. However, the negative binomial coefficients should be mentioned.