# Showing $\sum_{k=3}^{n} (-1)^{k}{n\choose k}\sum_{j=1}^{k-2}{j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2}=(-1)^{n-1} \left[\binom{n}{2}-\binom{2n+1}{n-2}\right]$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to prove the following binomial identity
$$
(*)\quad\quad\sum_{k=3}^{n}
     (-1)^{k}{n\choose k}\sum_{j=1}^{k-2}{j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2}=(-1)^{n-1} \left[\binom{n}{2}-\binom{2n+1}{n-2}\right]
$$
for every $n\geq 3$.
Let me say that $(*)$ is implied by the following binomial identity
$$
(**)\quad\quad\quad\quad \sum_{k=0}^{n}
     (-1)^{k}{n\choose k}F(k)=0
$$ 
which seems holding, for any $n\geq 0$, when defining
$$
F(k):=\sum_{j=1}^{k-2}{j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2}\quad \text{for $k\geq 3$}
$$
and
$$
F(2)=0\ ,\quad F(k):=-\sum_{j=k-1}^0{j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2}\quad \text{for $k=0,1$} 
$$
(latest definitions are given coherently with the principle of domain additivity, that is $\sum_{i=a}^bf(i)+\sum_{i=b+1}^cf(i)=\sum_{i=a}^cf(i)$, see e.g. the Phira's answer to [Upper limit of summation index lower than lower limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35080/upper-limit-of-summation-index-lower-than-lower-limit)). Anyway, I'm not able to prove identity $(**)$, as well!

Notice that $(**)$ is equivalent to say that there exist a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $\deg P\leq n-1$ such that 
$$
\forall\,k=0,\ldots,n\quad P(k)=F(k)
$$
by $n$-th finite difference. This fact seems not to be trivial, as the number of monomials of $F(k)$ depends on $k$, so $F$ is not directly a polynomial in $k$.

Comment: If we could ping @MarkusScheuer. He has some powerful magic in this area.

Answer (score 4):

We seek to verify that

$$\sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}
\sum_{j=1}^{k-2} {j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2}
= (-1)^{n-1} \left[ {n\choose 2} - {2n+1\choose n-2} \right].$$

where $n\ge 3.$ Now for

$$\sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} {k-3\choose n-2}$$

to be non-zero we would need $k-3\ge n-2$ or $k\ge n+1$, which is
not in the range, so it is zero and we may work with

$$\sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}
\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} {j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2}
\\ = \sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}
\sum_{j\ge 0} {j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2} [[0\le j\le k-2]]
\\ = \sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}
\sum_{j\ge 0} {j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2} 
\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^{k-1}} \frac{z^j}{1-z}
\\ = \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{z}{1-z}
\sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k}
\sum_{j\ge 0} {j(n+1)+k-3\choose n-2} z^j
\\ = \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{z}{1-z}
\sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k}
\sum_{j\ge 0} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}}
(1+w)^{j(n+1)+k-3} z^j
\\ = \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{z}{1-z}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} 
\sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k} (1+w)^{k-3}
\sum_{j\ge 0} (1+w)^{j(n+1)} z^j
\\ = \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{z}{1-z}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k} (1+w)^{k-3}
\\ = \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{z}{1-z}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^3}
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^{n+1}}
\\ \times \sum_{k=3}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k} (1+w)^{k}.$$

We compute  this by lowering  the index  to $k=0$ and  subtracting the
values  for $k=0,1$  and  $k=2$ from  this  completed sum.   **First**
(piece $A$), extending to $k=0$ we find

$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{z}{1-z}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^3}
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^{n+1}}
\left(1-\frac{1+w}{z}\right)^n
\\ =  \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^{n}} \frac{z}{1-z}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^3}
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^{n+1}} (z-1-w)^n.$$

We introduce  $z/(1+w-z) =  v$ so  that $z =  v(1+w)/(1+v)$ and  $dz =
(1+w)/(1+v)^2 \; dv$ as well as $z/(1-z) = v(1+w)/(1-vw)$ to get

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{v^n} 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^3}
\frac{v(1+w)}{1-vw} \frac{1}{1-v(1+w)^{n+2}/(1+v)}
\frac{1+w}{(1+v)^2}
\\ = \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{v^{n-1}} \frac{1}{1+v}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{1+w}
\frac{1}{1-vw}
\frac{1}{1-v((1+w)^{n+2}-1)}.$$

Observe that

$$\frac{1}{1+v} \frac{1}{1-vw}
= \frac{1}{1+w} \frac{1}{1+v} + \frac{w}{1+w} \frac{1}{1-vw}.$$

We thus have piece $A_1:$

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{v^{n-1}} \frac{1}{1+v}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\frac{1}{1-v((1+w)^{n+2}-1)}
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} (-1)^{n-2-q} ((1+w)^{n+2}-1)^q
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2}  (1-(1+w)^{n+2})^q
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\frac{1-(1-(1+w)^{n+2})^{n-1}}{(1+w)^{n+2}}
\\ = [w^{n-2}]
\frac{1-(-(n+2)w-\cdots-w^{n+2})^{n-1}}{(1+w)^{n+4}}
= (-1)^{n-2} {n-2+n+3\choose n-2} 
\\ = (-1)^n {2n+1\choose n-2}.$$

We have one correct piece.  Continuing with $A_2$ (which we conjecture
to be zero) we find

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{v^{n-1}}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-2}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\frac{1}{1-vw}
\frac{1}{1-v((1+w)^{n+2}-1)}
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{w^{n-2}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} w^{n-2-q} ((1+w)^{n+2}-1)^q
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{w^{n-2}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} w^{n-2-q} ((n+2)w+\cdots+w^{n+2})^q
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{(-1)^n}{w^{n-2}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} ((n+2)^q w^{n-2} +\cdots+w^{(n+1)q+n-2})
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;  \frac{(-1)^n}{(1+w)^2}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} ((n+2)^q +\cdots+w^{(n+1)q}) = 0.$$

Continuing with the **second** piece $B$ which corresponds to $k=0$

$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{z}{1-z}
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^3}
\frac{1}{1-z(1+w)^{n+1}}.$$

This is  zero by inspection  because there is  no pole at  $z=0.$ More
formally,

$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^3}
\\ \times \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; z ( 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots)
(1 + z (1 + w)^{n+1} + z^2 (1+w)^{2n+2}+\cdots) = 0.$$

For the **third** piece  $C$ which corresponds to $k=1$ we get a factor
of $-n (1+w)/z$ for

$$-n \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^2}
\\ \times \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; ( 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots)
(1 + z (1 + w)^{n+1} + z^2 (1+w)^{2n+2}+\cdots) = 0.$$

The factor for the **fourth** piece $D$ is ${n\choose 2} (1+w)^2/z^2:$

$${n\choose 2} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{1+w}
\\ \times \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z} ( 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots)
(1 + z (1 + w)^{n+1} + z^2 (1+w)^{2n+2}+\cdots) 
\\ = {n\choose 2} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n-1}} \frac{1}{1+w}
= (-1)^n {n\choose 2}.$$

Subtracting $B, C$ and $D$ from $A$ we finally obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^n \left[ {2n+1\choose n-2} - {n\choose 2} \right].}$$

Comment: Dear Marko,thank you for your interesting and deep answer. I spent some time to understand it in the detail. Given your proof of identity $(*)$

Comment: Given your proof of identity $(*)$, identity $(**)$ immediately follows. By solving a linear system, it is then possible to exhibiting a polynomial $P$ of degree $n-1$ and satisfying condition $P(k)=F(k)$, for any $0\leq k\leq n$. Viceversa, the existence of $P$ implies both $(*)$ and $(**)$. Exhibiting $P$ seems a purely algebraic task and I would be astonished if the only way to get it should pass through complex analysis... Someone have an algebraic proof of either $(*)$ or the existence of $P$?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Great answer. I went through it in a rather detailed way and verified it step by step. I appreciate the elegance how the Iverson brackets are treated  and the instructive substitution as well as the creative split into the pieces $A1$ and $A2$. (+1) of course. I found a good motivation for each of the steps besides the creative split. Would you mind to provide your thoughts about it.

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark and for vetting the calculation. At the point where I do the split I did not know yet whether I had the right path. A product of three geometric series turns into two nested sums, while a product of two gives just one sum. So I decided to try the latter and then I discovered I could in fact evaluate the two simple sums.