# Compute $\sum \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k-1}{k} (-1)^k$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How can we study a series like this :

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{k} (-1)^k$.

I thought about consider $S(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{k} x^k$. But the only one I've found is hypergeometric function. It's hard to analyze.

Hope there are more combinatorical ideas for finding such series.

Any hints? Maybe generating functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$[x^k]:f(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^k$ in the function $f(x)$. So for instance
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{k}=[x^k]: (1+x)^n.
\end{eqnarray*}

So for your sum we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k-1}{k} &=& [x^0]: \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \frac{(1+x)^{n+k-1}}{x^k} \\
&=& [x^0]: (1+x)^{n-1} \left(1- \frac{(1+x)}{x} \right)^n \\
&=& [x^n]: (1+x)^{n-1} (-1)^n =\color{red}{0}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 4):

Here we  have  the  *[Chu-Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*  in disguise.

> We     obtain         for        $n>0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{ \binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{k} (-1)^k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{-n}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{0}{n}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the   binomial identities  $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ and  $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use [shifted Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). Rodrigues' formula ensures

$$P_n(2x-1)=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}(-1)^k x^k $$
hence

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}(-1)^k\frac{n}{k+n}=n(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}P_n(2x-1)x^{n-1}\,dx $$
and the RHS is zero, since $P_n(2x-1)$ is orthogonal to any polynomial with degree less than $n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Using [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) and [Negative Binomial Coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k
&=\sum_k\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{-n}{k}\\
&=\binom{0}{n}\\[9pt]
&=[n=0]
\end{align}
$$
Note that $\binom{-1}{0}=1$.

---

**Using [Finite Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)**

For $n\ge1$,
$$
\sum_k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k
=\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}
$$
which is an order $n$ repeated difference of a degree $n-1$ polynomial, and therefore, vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
{n + k - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\bracks{{-\bracks{n + k - 1} + k - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}}\pars{-1}^{k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{-n \choose k}\ =\
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px solid navy]{\delta_{n0}}
\end{align}