# On a sum of binomial coefficients and inequalities

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, additive-combinatorics

Let $n\ge d\ge 3$ be positive integers.

Is there a closed form formula for $\sum_{i=0}^d \binom {n-d+i-1}{i}$ ? For what conditions on $n$ and $d$ can we say

$\sum_{i=0}^d \binom {n-d+i-1}{i} \le (n-d+1)(d-1)!$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^d\binom{n-d+i-1}{i}
&=\sum_{i=0}^d\binom{n-d+i-1}{i}\binom{d-i}{d-i}\tag1\\
&=(-1)^d\sum_{i=0}^d\binom{d-n}{i}\binom{-1}{d-i}\tag2\\
&=(-1)^d\binom{d-n-1}{d}\tag3\\
&=\binom{n}{d}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: multiply by $[d\ge i]$
$(2)$: apply [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$(3)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(4)$: apply negative binomial coefficients

---

$\binom{n}{d}\le(n-d+1)(d-1)!$ is equivalent to
$$
\binom{n}{d-1}\le d!\tag5
$$
For a rough approximation of $n$ in $(5)$, note that $\binom{n}{d-1}\le\frac{n^{d-1}}{(d-1)!}$, then we get that $(5)$ is true when
$$
n\le\left(d!(d-1)!\right)^{\frac1{d-1}}\sim\frac{d^2}{e^2}\tag6
$$
where the asymptotic approximation comes from [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as 
$$\sum_{i=0}^d \binom{n-d-1+i}{n-d-1} = \sum_{m=n-d-1}^{n-1} \binom{m}{n-d-1}$$
and then use the [Hockey Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) to evaluate this as 
$$\binom{n}{n-d}$$

---

As for the desired inequality, after some rearrangement it becomes equivalent to $$\binom{n}{d-1}\leq d!$$ For your stated criteria $n\geq d\geq 3$, this will generally hold for $d$ close to $n$, and will fail for small $d$.  I don't know of an easy analytic way to express the exact crossover from where the inequality fails to where it holds, but using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) you can get estimates.