# Combinatoric meaning to $1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}= {n+1 \choose 2}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

It is well known that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} .$$
As the story goes, Gauss notices that there are $n/2$ pairs of numbers that add up to $n+1$, hence the formula above.

But obviously the right hand side is ${n+1 \choose 2}$, namely
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k = {n+1 \choose 2} .$$
Is there a "combinatorial proof" of this second equation? I am trying to see the connection between the sum (and Gauss' method) to the problem of choosing $2$ objects from $n+1$ objects.

Comment: Interpreting $k$ instead as $\binom{k}{1}$ you can treat this as a special case of the [hockey stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1) and use the combinatorial interpretation and proof there.

Comment: @ArnaudD. It looks like it does but will have to digest it for a bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How many pairs can we obtain with $n+1$ objects?

- first and second, first and third, $\,\ldots= n$ pairs
- second and third, second and fourth, $\,\ldots= n-1$ pairs
- and so on $\,\ldots$

Comment: awesome thank you

Comment: @NazimJ You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

$1+2+3+4+\cdots+n\\
=\binom{1}{1}+\binom{2}{1}+\binom{3}1+\binom{4}1+\cdots+\binom{n}1\\
=\binom{2}{2}+\binom{2}1+\binom{3}1+\binom{4}1+\cdots+\binom{n}1$

and use $\binom{a}{b+1}+\binom{a}{b}=\binom{a+1}{b+1}$.

This may not be what you are looking for, but I think it's a little cool.

Answer (score 1):

This can be viewed as an instance of [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nk
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{k}{k-1}\binom{n-k}{n-k}\tag1\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{-2}{k-1}\binom{-1}{n-k}\tag2\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\binom{-3}{n-1}\tag3\\[3pt]
&=\binom{n+1}{n-1}\tag4\\[3pt]
&=\binom{n+1}{2}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{k}{k-1}=k\,[k\ge1]$ and $\binom{n-k}{n-k}=[k\le n]$
$(2)$: [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$(3)$: Vandermonde's Identity
$(4)$: negative binomial coefficients
$(5)$: symmetry of [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)