# Find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating functions: $g(x) = \frac{x^3}{(1+x)^5 (1−x)^6}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

One of the problems in my Discrete Math course states that we need to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in generating function $g(x) = \frac{x^3} {(1+x)^5 (1−x)^6}$

I separated $g(x) = \frac{x^3} {(1+x)^5 (1−x)^6}$ into $x^3$ * $\frac{1}{(1+x)^5}$ * $\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}$

Then got $f(x) = x^3 * \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+4}{4}(-1)^kx^k * \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+5}{5}x^k$

I dont know what to do from here, can you tell me what is the next step?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply two power series?

Comment: Hint: $g(x) = \dfrac{x^3(1 + x)}{(1 - x^2)^6}$.

Comment: According to https://oeis.org/A189980 it's $\displaystyle \binom{\lfloor \frac{n+7}{2} \rfloor}{5}$ (matches  also with some answers below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^3}{(1+x)^5 (1−x)^6}
&=\frac{x^3+x^4}{\left(1-x^2\right)^6}\tag1\\
&=\left(x^3+x^4\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-6}{k}x^{2k}\tag2\\
&=\left(x^3+x^4\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+5}{5}x^{2k}\tag3\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+5}{5}\left(x^{2k+3}+x^{2k+4}\right)\tag4\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\binom{k+3}{5}\left(x^{2k-1}+x^{2k}\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: multiply by $\frac{1+x}{1+x}$
$(2)$: use the series for $(1+x)^{-6}$
$(3)$: $\binom{-6}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{k+5}{5}$ when $k\ge0$
$\phantom{\text{(3):}}$ ([negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647))
$(4)$: distribute the $x^3+x^4$
$(5)$: substitute $k\mapsto k-2$

Thus, if $n=2k-1$ or $n=2k$, then the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\binom{k+3}{5}$.

This can be stated as the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\binom{\left\lfloor\frac{n+7}2\right\rfloor}{5}$

Comment: As often the top answer. (+1) :-)

Answer (score 2):

The key is the generalized binomial theorem
in the handy special case
$(1-x)^{-s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k}x^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
$.

This implies that

$(1+x)^{-s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k}(-1)^kx^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1}(-1)^kx^k
$

and,
for any $m$,

$(1-x^m)^{-s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k}x^{km}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^{km}
$.

For $m=2$ this is

$(1-x^2)^{-s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k}x^{2k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^{2k}
$.

Your problem is

$\begin{array}\\
g(x) 
&= \dfrac{x^3} {(1+x)^5 (1−x)^6}\\
&= \dfrac{x^3(1+x)} {(1+x)^6 (1−x)^6}\\
&= \dfrac{x^3(1+x)} {(1−x^2)^6}\\
&= \dfrac{x^3} {(1−x^2)^6}+\dfrac{x^4} {(1−x^2)^6}\\
\end{array}
$

The results above
should make this
straightforward.

---

Actually,
it's not that simple.
Here's the rest.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x^3} {(1−x^2)^6}
&=x^3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+5}{5}x^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+5}{5}x^{2k+3}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+5}{5}x^{2(k+1)+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{k+4}{5}x^{2k+1}\\
\\
\dfrac{x^4} {(1−x^2)^6}
&=x^4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+5}{5}x^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+5}{5}x^{2k+4}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{k+5}{5}x^{2(k+2)}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \binom{k+3}{5}x^{2k}\\
\end{array}
$

This gives the coefficients
of the even and odd terms.

To map these cases
into a single one,
use
$h(k)
=k-2\lfloor k/2 \rfloor
$
where
$h(k) = 0$ for even $k$
and
$h(k) = 1$ for odd $k$.

Since we want
even $k \to \lfloor k/2 \rfloor+3$
and
odd $k \to \lfloor k/2 \rfloor+4$,
we want

$\begin{array}\\
k 
&\to \lfloor k/2 \rfloor+3+h(k)\\
&\to \lfloor k/2 \rfloor+3+k-2\lfloor k/2 \rfloor\\
&\to k+3-\lfloor k/2 \rfloor\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$g(x)
=\sum_{k=3}^{\infty} x^k\binom{k+3-\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}{5}
$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Correct me if I am wrong since i am new to this. So using the rule above, I got $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+5}{5} *x^{2k - 3} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+5}{5} *x^{2k - 4}$ Then we group them together and get: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+5}{5} *(x^{2k-3} + x^{2k-4})$. From this point, how can i find the coefficient of $x^n$? I tried to group $x^{2k-3} + x^{2k-4}$ together and get $x^{2k-4} * (x+1)$ then sub n = 2k-4 but there is a (x+1) outside which still does not allow me to get $x^n$. Can you show me?

Comment: I added additional stuff to do this. Not as easy as I thought.

Comment: Thank you for the extra work. Then the coefficient of $x^n$ in this case would be $\sum_{k=3}^{n} \binom{k+3-\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}{5}$ right? I am new to this sorry.

Comment: No summation. Just the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation using the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ which denotes the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We start with $f(x)$ and obtain for $n\geq 3$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^n]f(x)}&=[x^n]x^3\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+4}{4}(-1)^kx^k\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{l+5}{5}x^l\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{n-3}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+4}{4}(-1)^kx^k\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{l+5}{5}x^l\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{k+4}{4}(-1)^k[x^{n-3-k}]\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{l+5}{5}x^l\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{k+4}{4}(-1)^k\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{l+5}{5}[x^{n-3-k}]x^l\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{k+4}{4}\binom{n-k+2}{5}(-1)^k}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the sums using different indices $k$ and $l$ which helps to not mix them up.
- In (2) we absorb $x^3$ by applying the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ again. Note the upper index is set to $n-3$, since other indices do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^{n-3}$.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^{n-3-k}$ which implies choosing $l=n-3-k$. Here we use $[x^p]x^q=\begin{cases}1&p=q\\0&p\ne q\end{cases}$.

Comment: How did you get from 2 to 3? I dont understand the part where [$x^{n-3}$] turn into [$x^{n-3-k}$]. Can you explain?

Comment: @TaAnhMin: I've missed to write $x^k$ in  (1) and (2). This is now corrected. Thanks for pointing to it.

Comment: Just to clarify. The step between 3 and 4 is $\sum_{k=0}^{n-3} \binom{k+4}{4} (-1)^k [n^{n-3-k}] \sum_{l=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-3-l+5}{5} x^l$. Since l and k use use for differentiate, we can set l = k and combine the 2 parts. We have: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-3} \binom{k +4}{4} \binom{n+2 -k}{5} (-1)^k [n^{n-3-k}]$. Since we only want the coefficient of $x^{n-3-k}$, we have: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{4+k}{4}\binom{n+2 -k}{5} (-1)^k$. Are my steps correct? Thank you

Comment: @TaAnhMinh: I've added some info which might be helpful.

Comment: (+1) Although I like negative binomial coefficients, sometimes people prefer to avoid them.