# Is there a way to find the sum of an infinite series (not geometric)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to calculate

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+3}k(0.2)^k$$

to get the exact value of it. I have excel and other tools to help me so it is fine if it is computationally expensive. Is there a clear and repeatable way to solve this infinite series? Thank you. This is my first post and be sure to give me some suggestions as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It’s a general fact that

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+n}nx^k=\frac1{(1-x)^{n+1}}\;.$$

You can prove this by induction on $n$, starting with the geometric series

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k$$

and differentiating repeatedly with respect to $x$. You want the case $n=3$:

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+3}kx^k=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+3}3x^k=\frac1{(1-x)^4}\,.$$

Now just substitute $x=0.2$.

Comment: Thanks :)
It's very helpful that you gave me a general answer as well.

Comment: @CELLSecret: You’re welcome.

Comment: Is there a way to to write out the expression on stackexchange without embedding an image? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: @CELLSecret Here is the typesetting tutorial : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Using the [negative binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647/13854) $\binom{-4}{k}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+3}{k}(0.2)^k
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-4}k(-1)^k(0.2)^k\\
&=(1-0.2)^{-4}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{625}{256}
\end{align}
$$