# Identity on the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}{i-1 \choose k}{n-2-i \choose k-1}={n-2 \choose 2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I need to evaluate the first summation for $k\geq1$ and $n\geq2$.
Some computer calculations allow the identification with the expression ${n-2 \choose 2k}$
above but, how can it be derived? Are there different methods or any
combinatorial interpretation?

Comment: Hint: Vandermonde's identity

Comment: I thought Vandermonde dealt with the lower indices. It can be made to work using negative binomial coefficients, but that's a bit more work than just Vandermonde.

Comment: Let us assume we pick $2k$ balls among $n-2$ which are in a line. Divide the possible cases as follows: $k$ choices are on the "left" of the $i^{th}$-ball, $k$ others are on the right, varying $i$ from $1$ to $n-2$ gives $n-2$ "divisions" of possible cases. (for each division, the number of choices is given by the summand on the l.h.s.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: From the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n-2\}$, choose $2k$ elements and let $i$ be the $(k+1)$-th element chosen, using the standard ordering. The first $k$ elements are chosen from $\{1, 2, \dots, i-1\}$ and the last $k - 1$ elements are chosen from $\{i+1, i+2, \dots, n-2\}$.

Comment: Thank you Michael, so we consider the set $S$ of $(n-2)$ elements
and a subset $C$ of $2k$ elements with a total of ${n-2 \choose 2k}$
choices. $C$ can be split into two equal halfs, taking as a fixed
demarcation point, denoted as $i$, the first element of the second
half, the $(k+1)^{th}$ element. Elements in each half of $C$ are
chosen idependently so we have the product of: ${i-1 \choose k}$
choices (from $\{1,2,\ldots,k-1\}$) with ${(n-2)-i \choose k-1}$
choices (from the remaining elements of $S$ once the elements of
the first half of $C$ are extracted $\{i+1,i-2,\ldots,n-2\}$.)

Comment: Finally we have to come back to the fixed point $i$ and consider all its possible
positions in $S$ in order to make their addition: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}$
resulting on the first part of the identity.

Answer (score 2):

**An Extension of Vandermonde's Identity**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{k\\n-k\ge a\\m+k\ge b}}\binom{n-k}{a}\binom{m+k}{b}
&=\sum_{k}\binom{n-k}{n-k-a}\binom{m+k}{m+k-b}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k}(-1)^{n-k-a}\binom{-a-1}{n-k-a}(-1)^{m+k-b}\binom{-b-1}{m+k-b}\tag2\\[9pt]
&=(-1)^{n+m-a-b}\binom{-a-b-2}{n+m-a-b}\tag3\\[9pt]
&=\binom{n+m+1}{n+m-a-b}\tag4\\[9pt]
&=\binom{n+m+1}{a+b+1}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: symmetry of Pascal's Triangle
$(2)$: [negative binomial coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$(3)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(4)$: negative binomial coefficients
$(5)$: symmetry of Pascal's Triangle

Applying $(5)$ gives
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\binom{i-1}{k}\binom{n-2-i}{k-1}=\binom{n-2}{2k}\tag6
$$

Comment: Negative binomial coefficients **really** are helpful, but when do we come to know that applying them should be a good idea?

Comment: @LightYagami: The Binomial Theorem sums on the lower index, which is why the vanilla Vandermonde Theorem does, too. When the summation is on the upper index, I will try negative binomial coefficients. Sometimes, when there is alternation, i.e. $(-1)^n$, that also indicates negative binomial coefficients might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, @robjohn. I like the strategy of using negative binomial coefficients to get rid of the counter $k$ from the upper index of the binomial coefficients in order to apply comfortably the Vandermonde's convolution, which acts with the counter $k$ in the lower index of the binomial numbers, and finaly revert the transformations.

Comment: @robjohn:Actually, I guess that, akin to a general
Vandermonde's identity for compositions of size $p$ of the numbers
$n=n_{1}+n_{2}+\ldots+n_{p}$ and $k=k_{1}+k_{2}+\ldots+k_{p}$ :

$\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+\ldots+k_{p}=k}{n_{1} \choose k_{1}}{n_{2} \choose k_{2}}\cdots{n_{p} \choose k_{p}}={n \choose k}$

Comment: @robjohn:We could extend this very same strategy through negative binomials
to the following genealization, where $a=a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots+a_{p}$
: 

$\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
k_{1}+k_{2}+\ldots+k_{p}\\
n_{i}+k_{i}\geq a_{i}
\end{array}}{n_{1}+k_{1} \choose a_{1}}{n_{1}+k_{1} \choose a_{2}}\cdots{n_{p}+k_{p} \choose a_{p}}={n+k+p-1 \choose p+a-1}$

Comment: @robjohn: We could procede analogously, if I am not mistaken:

$(1)=\sum_{k_{1}+\ldots+k_{p}}{n_{1}+k_{1} \choose n_{1}+k_{1}-a_{1}}{n_{1}+k_{1} \choose n_{1}+k_{1}-a_{2}}\cdots{n_{p}+k_{p} \choose n_{1}+k_{1}-a_{p}}$

$(2)=\sum_{k_{1}+\ldots+k_{p}}(-1)^{(n_{1}+k_{1}-a_{1})}{-a_{1}-1 \choose n_{1}+k_{1}-a_{1}}\cdots(-1)^{(n_{1}+k_{1}-a_{p})}{-a_{p}-1 \choose n_{1}+k_{1}-a_{p}}$

$(3)=(-1)^{\sum n_{i}+\sum k_{i}-\sum a_{i}}{-\sum a_{i}-p \choose \sum n_{i}+\sum k_{i}-\sum a_{i}}=(-1)^{n+k-a}{-a-p \choose n+k-a}$

$(4)={n+k+p-1 \choose n+k-a}$

$(5)={n+k+p-1 \choose p+a-1}$

Comment: Those look reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to verify that

$$\sum_{q=1}^n {q-1\choose k} {n-q\choose k-1} =
{n\choose 2k}$$

using that $k\ge 1$ and $n\ge 1$ we get
$q-1\ge k$ and $q\le n-k+1$ and may re-write as

$$\sum_{q=k+1}^{n-k+1} {q-1\choose k} {n-q\choose k-1}
= \sum_{q=0}^{n-2k} {q+k\choose k} {n-(k+1)-q\choose k-1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-2k} {q+k\choose k} {n-k-1-q\choose n-2k-q}
= [z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^{n-k-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2k} {q+k\choose k} \frac{z^q}{(1+z)^q}.$$

Now the coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the sum
and we may extend $q$ to infinity, getting

$$[z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^{n-k-1}
\frac{1}{(1-z/(1+z))^{k+1}}
= [z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^{n-k-1} (1+z)^{k+1}
\\ = [z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^n = {n\choose n-2k} = {n\choose 2k}.$$

This is the claim.