# Curious Binomial identity that came up in derivative pricing

Tags: combinatorics

How can I show that, for a given integer $n$, that the following identity is true?
$$\left[(-1)^n\binom{n-1}{m}-\sum_{k=m}^{n-2}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{k}{m}\right]=-(-1)^m$$

This came up in a derivation of arbitrary derivatives of the Black-Scholes function.  It is part of a larger equation for the $n^{th}$ order derivative
$$\sum_{m=0}^{n-2}\frac{H_m(d)}{(\sigma\sqrt{\tau})^m}\left[(-1)^n\binom{n-1}{m}-\sum_{k=m}^{n-2}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{k}{m}\right]$$
which, in order to make contact with a known result (Carr, Peter. (2000). Deriving Derivatives of Derivative Securities. Journal of Computational Finance. 4. 101 - 128.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/844609) this identity must hold.  I've also checked that it's true in sagemath.

Comment: Note you just pulled out the $k=n-1$ term.  Move that in, clear a few signs, use [this question](/q/1890530) and induct

Comment: @user10354138 It seems you can't induct easily because of the $n$ in the summand; also applying the referenced result is not simple since $k \neq k+1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&(-1)^n\binom{n-1}{m}-\sum_{k=m}^{n-2}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k+1}\binom{k}{m}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{n-k-1}\binom{k}{k-m}\tag1\\
&=(-1)^{m+1}\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-k-1}\binom{-m-1}{k-m}\tag2\\
&=(-1)^{m+1}\binom{n-m-1}{n-m-1}\tag3\\[9pt]
&=(-1)^{m+1}[n\ge m+1]\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $(-1)^n\binom{n-1}{m}$ becomes the $m=n-1$ term of the sum
$\phantom{\text{(1):}}$ furthermore, $\binom{k}{m}=\binom{k}{k-m}$
$(2)$: $\binom{k}{k-m}=(-1)^{k-m}\binom{-m-1}{k-m}$ ([negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647))
$(3)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(4)$: [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Comment: The first step relies on $n \geq m+1$ already, and the OP's formula would run into troubles for $n = 0$ anyway. So I think $n \geq m+1$ should just be a standing requirement here.

Comment: Yes, m<n-1 indeed in the application I am looking at.  Thank you all, I now need to see if I can simplify the calc.

Comment: If binomial identities are formulated properly, the limits of the indices can often be left out, or at least simplified. In this case, $\binom{n}{k+1}=0$ if $k\gt n-1$ and $\binom{k}{m}=0$ if $0\le k\lt m$. We do constrain $k\ge0$ since if $k\lt0$ we don't have $\binom{k}{m}=\binom{k}{k-m}$. Thus, if we simply sum over all $k\ge0$, the limits are imposed by the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Does Vandermonde's Identity still hold when the sum does not start from $0$?

Comment: The bottom indices go to $0$ at the ends of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Have an alternative solution that takes a different approach than [the one here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4048592/101653). Consider mine more opaque and involved, but worth sharing for the fun of it.

We start with Eq. 1.23 in [this reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20171118024544/http://www.math.wvu.edu/%7Egould/Vol.2.PDF) changing the labeling for convenience
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n'}(-1)^k \binom {n'} k \binom {k} m x^k=(-1)^mx^m(1-x)^{n'-m} \binom{n'}{m} $$
and apply $\binom n k = \frac{n}{k} \binom {n-1} {k-1}$ as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n'}(-1)^k \frac{k+1}{n'+1}\binom {n'+1} {k+1} \binom {k} m x^k=(-1)^mx^m(1-x)^{n'-m} \binom{n'}{m}. $$
Substitution $n=n'+1$ then yields
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \frac{k+1}{n}\binom {n} {k+1} \binom {k} m x^k=(-1)^mx^m(1-x)^{n-m-1} \binom{n-1}{m}. $$
Integrate both sides, assume that constants are 0, $x=1$ to get
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \binom {n} {k+1} \binom {k} m=\frac{(-1)^m}{n}. $$
Integral on the RHS is tricky in general, but evaluates nicely in the present case.

Now we can split off the $n-1$ term from the sum and multiply by $n$ to obtain
$$(-1)^{n-1} \binom {n-1} m + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k \binom {n} {k+1} \binom {k} m=(-1)^m. $$
Finally, we multiply by $-1$, note that binomial coefficients with $k < m$ in the sum are 0 and get
$$(-1)^{n} \binom {n-1} m - \sum_{k=m}^{n-2}(-1)^k \binom {n} {k+1} \binom {k} m=-(-1)^m. $$