# A simple question on binomial.(a Typo or not?)

Tags: probability, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, random-walk

[image]

This is an old paper by W.Feller.

It says that

$$  \sum_{k=r}^{n-1} \binom{k}{r}\binom{2n-2-k}{n-1} = \binom{2n-1}{n-1-r}$$

But I think, by Vandermonde's Identity, it's $\binom{2n-2}{n-1-r}$

Let $$p = k-r, then \sum_{p=0}^{n-1-r} \binom{k}{k-r}\binom{2n-2-k}{n-1-k} = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1-r} \binom{k}{p}\binom{2n-2-k}{(n-1-r)-p} = \binom{2n-2}{n-1-r}$$

Is it just a Typo or not?

Comment: This is because I already found a few of typos in this paper.

Comment: I've made a sanity check for $n=4$ and $r=2$ and obtained $7$. This result is the same result as in the paper. And it is a counter example for your result.

Comment: It looks correct. There is a Vandermonde identity for when the top indices are constant and the bottom ones add up to a constant, and vice versa. It is the other one you use here, and all works out fine.

Comment: Leave a comment to let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Let $p = k-r$ then $\sum_{p=0}^{n-1-r} \binom{k}{k-r}\binom{2n-2-k}{n-1-k} = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1-r} \binom{k}{p}\binom{2n-2-k}{(n-1-r)-p} = \binom{2n-2}{n-1-r} $

Comment: One thing I might miss out is that top indices are not (actually) constant? So I did not apply Vandermonde to it correctly? Then, Can you show me why 2n-1? What's the well-known binomial coefficients formula the author mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=r}^{n-1}\binom{k}{r}\binom{2n-2-k}{n-1}
&=\sum_{k=r}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-r}\binom{-r-1}{k-r}(-1)^{n-1-k}\binom{-n}{n-1-k}\tag{1a}\\
&=(-1)^{n-r-1}\binom{-n-r-1}{n-r-1}\tag{1b}\\
&=\binom{2n-1}{n-r-1}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ [negative binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217647)
$\text{(1b):}$ Vandermonde
$\text{(1c):}$ negative binomial coefficients

---

**Vandermonde in the Upper Parameters**

The Binomial Theorem says that
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{-n-1}(1+x)^{-m-1}
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j\binom{n+j}{n}x^j\ \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{m+k}{m}x^k\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=j}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{n+j}{n}\binom{m+k-j}{m}x^k\tag{2b}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^k\binom{n+j}{n}\binom{m+k-j}{m}x^k\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
and that
$$
(1+x)^{-(n+m+1)-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{n+m+1+k}{n+m+1}x^k\tag3
$$
Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ together, gives
$$
\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n+j}{n}\binom{m+k-j}{m}=\binom{n+m+k+1}{n+m+1}\tag4
$$
Thus, when the summation is carried out in the upper parameter of the binomial coefficients, an extra $1$ needs to be added in the upper and lower parameters in the resultant binomial coefficient, as compared to the standard Vandermonde Identity.

Comment: WOW. Thank you very much. I think your answer is a perfect one. By the way, Exactly What was my fallacy in using standard Vandermonde in the first place?

Comment: In the substitution of $p+r$ for $k$, the lower parameter was substituted, but the upper parameter was not. The upper parameter still contains $k$, which varies in the sum, and that $k$ was treated as a constant in your application of Vandermonde.

Comment: That was my mistake. Thank you again. :)

Comment: Can I ask one more thing relating to the previous one? How about this one? $$\sum_{v-1=0}^{n-1}\binom{2v}{v-1}\binom{2n-2v}{n-v}$$ My guessing is $\binom{2n}{n-1}$ and I finally got to know both uppers and lowers contains variables so that I can't apply Valdermonde, thanks to you, but I feel like it is quite reasonable because that means a path from origin to -2 passing through X-axis ONCE in symmetric randomwalk.

Comment: I don't think that has a simple sum. Note that for $n=2$, your guess fails.