# How to calclute the probability?

Tags: probability

A random function $rand()$ return a integer between $1$ and $k$ with the probability $\frac{1}{k}$. After $n$ times we obtain a sequence $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $1\leq b_i\leq k$.
Set $\mathbb{M}=\{b_1\}\cup\{b_2\}\cdots \cup\{b_n\}$, $\mathbb{N}=\{b_1\}\cup\{b_2\}\cdots \cup\{b_{n-1}\}$,

I want to calclute the probability satisfy the following condition:

$\mathbb{M}=\{1, 2\cdots, k\}$ and $\mathbb{N}\neq\{1, 2\cdots, k\}$.

Denoting the probality with $P(n)$. If $1\leq n< k$, then $P(n)=0$.
$P(n)=?$, where $n\geq k$.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that $j$ of the $k$ numbers is excluded is $(1-j/k)^n$ and there are $\binom{k}{j}$ ways to choose those $j$ to be excluded. The [generalized inclusion-exclusion principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516) says that the probability that *exactly* one of the $k$ numbers is excluded after $n-1$ trials is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}j\binom{k}{j}\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^{n-1}
=k\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k-1}{j-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^{n-1}
$$
Then the probability to pick the right one to finish on trial $n$ is $1/k$. Thus, the probability that you've just finished on trial $n$ is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k-1}{j-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^{n-1}
$$

---

**Another method**

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/368121), it is shown that the probability of still having at least one of the $k$ numbers excluded is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^n
$$
Subtracting from $1$, we get that the probability of getting all $k$ numbers by trial $n$ is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^n
$$
To get the probability that we get all $k$ numbers on trial $n$, take the difference between this for $n$ and $n-1$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\left[\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^{n-1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}\frac{j}{k}\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k-1}{j-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{k}\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  to succeed, $\Bbb N$ has to be missing exactly one element and $b_n$ has to be that element.

Comment: Tks very mach. I think this hint so public knowlegde. For express the problem more clearly, I discribe it as above.

Comment: @Yuanshengliu:  many of our posters would not have seen that, so it would have been helpful for them.  Do you have any thoughts on calculating the probability that $|\Bbb M|=k-1$?  I have a recurrence approach for specific $k$, but nothing to offer for general $k$.