# Probabilities of Unique Numbers in Roulette

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

To begin with I know there is a similar question asked and answered, but it is not what exactly i was trying to find (or at least it was only partially answered there) the question that i refer to is: [Probability of number of unique numbers in $37$ Roulette Wheel spins.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437172/probability-of-number-of-unique-numbers-in-37-roulette-wheel-spins)

I would like it if someone could tell me how to find the probability of $1$ unique number coming up in $37$ spins, $2$ unique numbers coming up in $37$ spins and $3,4 \dots 36,37$ unique numbers in $37$ spins.

I know there is a type explained in the mentioned question above that shows how to calculate the probability  of unique numbers.
[The probability of unique numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDJIA.jpg)

My problem is I don't have that much experience or knowledge with such advanced statistics, and I can't understand how the type can be translated into numbers for calculation and result. So my actual question is: how can I turn this type into calculations? This would enable me to find all the probabilities I want alone, without asking for further help. I would just like to know how this type turns into the result:
2157142399433325078661979618737564774321235951616000000000

If I can get there I can divide it easily with $37^{37}$ to get the probabilities.

Thanks for any replies in advance. :/

Comment: How many zeroes does your roulette wheel have?

Comment: it's european roulette. roulette with 1 zero.