# Combinatoric proof for $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left(-1\right)^k\left(n-k\right)^4 = 0$ ($n\geqslant5$)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to prove the following:

For every $n \ge 5$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left(-1\right)^k\left(n-k\right)^4 = 0$$

I've tried cancelling one $(n-k)$, and got this:
$$n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\left(-1\right)^k\left(n-k\right)^3 = 0$$

I've also tried expressing the first formula as such:
$$\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_k$$
Where $a_k = {n \choose k}\left(-1\right)^k$ and $b_k = \left(n-k\right)^4 = \sum_{j=0}^4{4\choose j}n^j\left(-k\right)^{4-j}$

It's easy to see that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k = \left(1-1\right)^n = 0$ by the binomial theorem.

But I'm lost as to why this work only for n>=5. What am I missing?

Comment: Any idea to start could be to consider the derivative of $(X-1)^n$ at $1$, evaluated in two different ways as you did for $(X-1)^n$. And to continue from there. I am not sure if this works though; it is merely an idea.

Comment: I thought of that, but not sure how this would get me to the required $\left(n-k\right)^4$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression counts the number of ways to partition a set of $4$ elements into $n$ distinguishable non-empty cells, which certainly must give zero for $n \geq 5$.

The result follows by inclusion exclusion. Alternately, see Stirling numbers of the second kind for a more general view.

Comment: Perfect! So is this the correct way of thinking?
Let $A = \{a, b, c, d\}$ so that $|A| = 4$, and let $B = \{1, ..., n\}$ so that $|B| = n$.

So we're looking for $|\{f: A -> B: f is injective\}|$. Total number of functions from A to B is $n^4$.
Let Sk be defined as $S_k = |\{f: A -> B\\\{k\}\}|$?

Comment: @hyit You look to be on the right track, except that you might have meant _surjective_.

Comment: But surjective doesn't mean that the partition is distinct, does it?

Comment: @hyit Ah, I made an error: distinguishable, not distinct. By phrasing the problem with functions on four elements, you automatically get this. What you don't automatically get is non-emptiness of partitions, which surjectivity provides.

Answer (score 5):

$p(k)=k^4$ is a fourth degree polynomial. Let $\delta$ be the backward difference operator:
$$ \delta f(x) = f(x)-f(x-1).$$
Since the degree of $\delta f$ is one less than the degree of $f$, for any $n\geq 5$ we have $\delta^n p(x) = 0$.

Comment: This is the result of the first equation in my answer. I thought that it required a bit more justification. Perhaps I was wrong :-) BTW, the operator in the question is the backward difference operator.

Comment: @robjohn: I always have some little problem about the nomenclature (especially because it looked natural to me to use the substitution $k\to n-k$), but the conclusion still holds by replacing the backward difference with the forward difference.

Comment: I was just mentioning in case you wanted to change $\delta f(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$ to match the question. I wasn't saying that your answer was insufficient.

Comment: @robjohn: I know, I know. Anyway, now it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of cancelling the factors of $n-k$ should work.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{m-1}\\
&-n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}(n-k)^{m-1}\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}(n-k)^{m-1}\\
\end{align}
$$
For $m\le n$, induction yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m
&=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}(-1)^k\binom{n-m}{k}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}(1-1)^{n-m}\\
&=\left\{
\begin{array}{}
n!&\text{if }m=n\\
0&\text{if }m\lt n
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Second Approach**

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516) there are three proofs of
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k}\binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{k}
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
1&\text{if }n=k\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\\
&=[n=k]
\end{align}
$$
where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Furthermore, $\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{{#1}\atop{#2}\right\}}$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{k}\,\stirtwo{m}{k}k!=n^m
$$
where $\stirtwo{m}{k}$ are [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(x-k)^m
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m(-1)^{k-j}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{j}x^{m-j}k^j\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^{k-j}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{j}x^{m-j}\binom{k}{i}\stirtwo{j}{i}i!\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^{n-j}\binom{m}{j}x^{m-j}\,[n=i]\,\stirtwo{j}{i}i!\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m(-1)^{n-j}\binom{m}{j}x^{m-j}\stirtwo{j}{n}n!
\end{align}
$$
If $m\lt n$, then either $\binom{m}{j}=0$ or $\stirtwo{j}{n}=0$. If $m=n$, the only non-zero term is $j=m$.

Comment: Amazing!
Doesn't this assume that $0^0 = 0$?
Also, I know $\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-1\right)^k {n\choose k} = \left(1-1\right)^n$, but how did you get the greater formula?

Comment: @hyit: it is just the binomial theorem; expand $(1-1)^{n-m}$

Comment: Then you just multiplied both parts of the equation by $\frac{n!}{\left(n-m\right)!}$ ?

Comment: @hyit: yes; so that it matches the formula gotten by induction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $j=n-k$ be the new iterator, and use $\displaystyle{n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$. You will arrive at a slightly simpler expression. To evaluate it, expand $(1+x)^n$, and differentiate both sides with regard to *x*, then multiply both sides by *x*. Repeat these two steps four times. Lastly, set $x=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

It will be useful to know:

$\mathbf{ Theorem.}$ Let    $p(x)= a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n$ be  $\mathit{any}$   polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ (of degree $\leq n$), then

$$ \sum_{k} {n\choose k}(-1)^k p(k)=(-1)^n n! a_n.$$
So in particular when $p$ has degree<n, then such sums are $0$.

Proof: see Graham, Knuth, Patashnik, Concrete Mathematics, Addison Wesley, 1989 , formula (5.42).
(As was suggested  above the proof is by using difference operators. ) $\Box$

Concerning the original question, since   $x\mapsto (n-x)^4$ is of degree 4 in $x$ but $n\geq 5 $ we get 0.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k (n-k)^q$$

where $q\ge 0.$ This is

$$q! [z^q] \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \exp((n-k)z).$$

We obtain

$$q! [z^q]  \exp(nz)
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \exp(-kz)
\\ = q! [z^q] \exp(nz) (1-\exp(-z))^n
\\ = q! [z^q] (\exp(z)-1)^n.$$

Now since $(\exp(z)-1)^n = z^n + \cdots$ this is zero when $q\lt n$ and
we have the claim. Observe that the EGF here yields $n! \times {q\brace
n}.$