# Does this identity have a name? $\sum_{i=0}^n [(-1)^i{n\choose{i}}i^k]=0$

Tags: summation, terminology, binomial-coefficients

Just what is asked in the title, with $k$ an integer such that $0\le k<n$.

Comment: I don't know that it has a name, but we have a proof of it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617965

Comment: Thanks, but I do have a proof. I just wanted to know in which context does this usually pop up and possibly a name associated with it.

Comment: There are an unbounded number of identities. Only a few of them are named. This is not one of them, but perhaps it deserves to be named.

Comment: I hereby name the identity *Graviton's Identity*. Those not in favour I will be dueling at sundown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the (forward) finite Difference of a function, being defined as
$$
\Delta f(x) = f(x + 1) - f(x)
$$
and its iteration
$$
\Delta ^n f(x) = \Delta \left( {\Delta ^{n - 1} f(x)} \right) =
= \sum\limits_{\left( {0 \le } \right)k\left( { \le n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k}
 \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\  k \\  \end{array} \right)f(x + k)} 
$$

Then
$$
\left. {\Delta ^n x^m } \right|_{x = 0}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0 \le } \right)k\left( { \le n} \right)}
 {\left( { - 1} \right)^{n - k} \left( \begin{array}{c}
 n \\  k \\  \end{array} \right)k^m } \left. {\Delta ^n x^m } \right|_{x = 0}  =
 \left( { - 1} \right)^n \sum\limits_{\left( {0 \le } \right)k\left( { \le n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k
 \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\  k \\  \end{array} \right)k^m } 
$$
So what you are having is $(-1)^n$ times the $n$-th difference of $x^k$ computed at $x=0$,
hence the relation with the Stirling N. .

Answer (score 2):

The sum $\sum _{i=0}^n (-1)^i i^k \binom{n}{i}$ is known as $(-1)^n n! \mathcal{S}_k^{(n)}$, involving the so-called Stirling number of second kind, denoted as $\mathcal{S}_k^{(n)}$.