# n balls are thrown indepently into n boxes. What is the probability there is exactly one box empty?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

I am struggling to count the total number of possible outcomes, I assume it is easier to count the outcomes ignoring the order of the balls and the numbering of the boxes?

Comment: Are the balls different? And the boxes?

Comment: It doesn't matter. @ajotatxe The probability is the same either way. You have been brainwashed by bad probability courses. (Combinatorics-wise, it would matter if you were counting the number of different ways for the result to happen.)

Comment: I know it won't make any difference, but presumably one way is going to be easier to calculate. And no, the balls and boxes are identical.

Comment: Sorry, but if it doesn't matter, you can assume either one you want, so the question is pointless. @user214713

Comment: My question was which way is easier not which one is correct.

Comment: Let us assume say that balls are indistinguishable but boxes are labelled. Then you can use Stars and Bars to count the number of "patterns" and you can count the "favourable" patterns. So far so good. But dividing **will not** give the right probability. For the patterns are not all equally likely. The great advantage of using the $n^n$ element sample space is that all members are equally likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly one ball must be thrown into a box where allready one ball is present. This cannot happen of course with the first ball. The probability that this happens with the $k+1$-th ball is:
$$\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n}\frac{k}{n}\frac{n-k}{n}\cdots\frac{2}{n}$$
This for $k=1,\dots,n-1$.

Do you understand why?

Addition of these probabilities gives you the answer to your question.

Comment: I understand why this works, but it is it possible to evaluate the summation to get a neater answer?

Comment: Sure. The probability that it happens with the $k+1$ ball is evidently $k\times n!\times n^{-n}$ and addition of these terms gives $\frac12n!n^{1-n}(n-1)$

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

**Simple Method**

For each of the $n!$ permutations of the $n$ balls into $n$ buckets, and a given pair of balls, there is another permutation that swaps the given pair of balls. These two permutations and this pair of balls define two unique arrangements where one bucket is empty: one where each element of the pair is moved to the other's bucket. Thus,  we get
$$
\binom{n}{2}n!\tag{1}
$$
arrangements with one bucket empty. There are $n^n$ arrangements of the $n$ balls into $n$ buckets, giving a probability of
$$
\binom{n}{2}\frac{n!}{n^n}\tag{2}
$$

---

**Inclusion-Exclusion**

We can also use the formula for Generalized Inclusion-Exclusion derived in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516) to get the count in $(1)$.

Let $S(j)$ be the number of arrangements with bin $j$ empty. Then the sum of the sizes of the intersections of $k$ of the $S(j)$ is
$$
N(k)=\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n\tag{3}
$$
The number of elements in exactly $1$ of the $S(j)$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{k}{1}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n\tag{4}
$$
Using the defining identity for [Stirling numbers of the Second Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
$$
\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{{#1}\atop{#2}\right\}}
\sum_{k=0}^n\stirtwo{n}{k}\binom{x}{k}k!=x^n\tag{5}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{k}{1}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(n-k)^n\tag{6a}\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k-1}\binom{n-1}{k}k^n\tag{6b}\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-k-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\stirtwo{n}{j}\binom{k}{j}j!\tag{6c}\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-k-1}\binom{n-1}{j}\stirtwo{n}{j}\binom{n-1-j}{k-j}j!\tag{6d}\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k-1}\stirtwo{n}{n-1}\binom{0}{k-n+1}(n-1)!\tag{6e}\\[4pt]
&=\stirtwo{n}{n-1}n!\tag{6f}\\[6pt]
&=\binom{n}{2}n!\tag{6g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(6a)}$: $\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{k-j}$
$\text{(6b)}$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ then change variables $k\mapsto n-k$
$\text{(6c)}$: apply $(5)$
$\text{(6d)}$: $\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{k-j}$
$\text{(6e)}$: $j=n$ is removed by $\binom{n-1}{j}$ and $j\lt n-1$ is removed since $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}=0$ for $n\gt0$
$\text{(6f)}$: $\binom{0}{k-n+1}$ removes all but $k=n-1$
$\text{(6g)}$: $\stirtwo{n}{n-1}=\binom{n}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  to get exactly one bin empty, you can arrange the balls one per bin, then move one ball to another bin.  How many different ways are there to get the same final configuration?