# How can I count solutions to $x_1 + \ldots + x_n = N$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am interested in how many non-negative integer solutions there are to:

$$x_1 + \ldots + x_N = B$$

where at least $K$ of the variables $x_1, \ldots , x_N \geq C$

For example when:
$B = 5, N = 3, K = 2, C = 2$

I want to count the solutions to:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 5$$

where at least $2$ of the variables are $\geq 2$.

I found the total number of candidate solutions using the $\binom{B+N-1}{B} = 21$

However, only $9$ of them have two variables $\geq 2$.

\begin{align*}
    2+0+3& =5\\
    2+1+2& =5\\
    3+0+2& =5\\
    1+2+2& =5\\
    3+2+0& =5\\
    0+2+3& =5\\
    0+3+2& =5\\
    2+3+0& =5\\
    2+2+1& =5
\end{align*}

I feel there is a connection to the Associated Stirling numbers of the second kind. But I can't place it :(

EDIT:

Here is my code for enumerating them all to count the number of ways of select B elements from a set of N (uniformly with replacement), such that you have at least C copies of K elements - also shows the output for this question I'm asking here as it's the core piece. Obviously can't be run for very large values of the parameters - that's why I'm here :) [Code is here](https://gist.github.com/nickponline/333f6d4f9ed039d8c9a5)

Here is another example for B = 6, N = 3, C = 2 and K = 2 there are 16 solutions:

\begin{align*}
0+2+4& = 6\\
0+3+3& = 6\\
0+4+2& = 6\\
1+2+3& = 6\\
1+3+2& = 6\\
2+0+4& = 6\\
2+1+3& = 6\\
2+2+2& = 6\\
2+3+1& = 6\\
2+4+0& = 6\\
3+0+3& = 6\\
3+1+2& = 6\\
3+2+1& = 6\\
3+3+0& = 6\\
4+0+2& = 6\\
4+2+0& = 6\\
\end{align*}

There are a number of different and correct solutions below. I don't know which to accept.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @nickponline I have a result now, can you check it?

Comment: Sure will check it now. I have some code for enumerating all the solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the set of solutions in nonnegative integers to $x_1+\cdots+x_n=B$ with $x_i\ge C$, for $1\le i\le n$,

and let $T_l=\sum\big|A_{i_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_l}\big|$, where the sum is taken over all $l$-subsets of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, for $1\le l\le n$.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, the number of elements in at least k of $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ is given by

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=k}^n(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i-1}{k-1}T_i=\color{blue}{\sum_{i=k}^n(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{B-Ci+n-1}{n-1}}$

since $T_i$ is the sum of $\binom{n}{i}$ terms, each of which has the value $\binom{B-Ci+n-1}{n-1}$.

---

See also this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516
for a related version of Inclusion-Exclusion.

---

Here are a few examples, which have been verified by considering cases:

$\textbf{1)}$ $B=6, n=3, C=2, k=2$:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^3(-1)^{i-2}\binom{i-1}{1}\binom{3}{i}\binom{8-2i}{2}=\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2}-\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{3}\binom{2}{2}=18-2=\color{blue}{16}$

$\textbf{2)}$ $B=12, n=5, C=4, k=2$:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^5(-1)^{i-2}\binom{i-1}{1}\binom{5}{i}\binom{16-4i}{4}=\binom{1}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{8}{4}-\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{4}=700-20=\color{blue}{680}$

$\textbf{3)}$ $B=18, n=6, C=3, k=4$:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=4}^6(-1)^{i-4}\binom{i-1}{3}\binom{6}{i}\binom{23-3i}{5}=\binom{3}{3}\binom{6}{4}\binom{11}{5}-\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{5}\binom{8}{5}+\binom{5}{3}\binom{6}{6}\binom{5}{5}=\color{blue}{5,596}$

Comment: What are c_i  values?

Comment: sorry - I had a slight typo; (I have only checked it in the case you gave, and the case B=12, n=5, k=2, C=4)

Comment: In my example C is 2 does this mean all the C_i are 2 as well?

Comment: No, the last factor in this case is $\binom{5-2i+2}{2}=\binom{7-2i}{2}$

Comment: Ah i see sorry i though it was a subscript

Comment: My use of a small c was misleading -- I am using the same idea as in the previous answers to get the expression for $T_i$

Comment: For B = 6, N = 3, C = 2, K = 2 your solution gives -20 where as the correct answer is 16. I posted this is the question. Also this is within the B-KC <= C so should not double count.

Comment: @nickponline: I think that is the same side effect of the fact that Mathematica (consistently) does not take $\binom{a}{b}$ as zero if $a<b$, but here we are clearly assuming that.

Comment: @nickponline I have edited my answer to give some examples.

Comment: Thank you this is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Without loss of generalization, let us consider $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k \geq C$.

Then let

$$y_i = \begin{cases}x_i - C &i\leq k\\ x_i & i > k \end{cases}$$

Solving

$$\left\{\begin{array}[lll] xx_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n &=& N\\ x_i \geq 0& &  \\ x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k& \geq & C\end{array}\right.$$ 
is equivalent to just solving 
$$\left\{\begin{array}[lll] yy_1 + y_2 + \ldots + y_n &=& N-kC\\ y_i \geq 0& &\end{array}\right.$$  The number of solutions excluding permutations is the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) of $N-kC$ into $m$ integers where $m \leq n$.

For each of this solutions, adding $C$ to $k$ of them would yield a solution of your original problem. There are $n\choose k$ ways to do thus but we are overcounting some solutions if there are $i,j$ such that $y_i = y_j$ or if $y_i + C = y_j$. For each of this solutions we have at most $n!$ distinct solutions (including permutations), again we are overcounting some if there are $i,j$ such that $y_i = y_j$ or if $y_i + C = y_j$. This gives us a somewhat close upper bound on the amount of solutions:

$${n\choose k} n!\sum_{m=1}^n P_m(N-kC)$$

Comment: But this example includes permutations since $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is an ordered pair. Order matters here. (Hence the discussion of partitions is also not needed)

Comment: Also, as I say on the other post, it's not so easy to just say "without loss of generality" and assume $x_1, \dots, x_k \geq C$. Since they're ordered, you also have to consider cases where different variables are included in the "at least K." And, this is NOT so easy as just multiplying the term by ${n \choose k}$ since this causes double counting when $N - CK > C$.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the double counted solutions by find an expression for them and subtracting it?

Answer (score 4):

A tailor-made approach by analytic combinatorics. The coefficient of $x^B$ in

$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^N} = \left(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots\right)^N $$
obviously counts the number of ways of representing $B$ as a sum of $N$ non-negative integers. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), or by the (negative) binomial theorem, such number is $\binom{N+B-1}{N-1}$. We may use an extra variable to mark the terms with exponent $\geq C$, and consider:
$$ g(z,x) = \left(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{C-1}+ z x^{C}+z x^{C+1}+ z x^{C+2}+\ldots\right)^N $$
that is:
$$ g(z,x) = \left(\frac{1-x^C}{1-x}+z\cdot\frac{x^C}{1-x}\right)^N = \frac{(1+(z-1) x^C)^N}{(1-x)^N}.$$
Now the coefficient of $x^B$ in $g(z,x)$ is a polynomial in the $z$ variable, $h_B(z)$, and we are interested in summing the monomials of $h_B(z)$ whose degree is $\geq K$. That sum evaluated at $z=1$ gives the answer to our problem. However, I suspect there is no nice closed formula for summarizing the process, since even the computation of $h_B(z)$ involves a convolution. Are you fine with an integral representation of the answer? That is not hard to achieve through Cauchy's integral formula.

If $B=5,N=3, C=2$ and $K=2$, we have $h_B(z)=12z+\color{red}{9}z^2$, hence the answer is $\color{red}{9}$ as you checked. The general form of the answer is given by:

> $$\begin{eqnarray*} [x^B]\sum_{D\geq K}[z^D]\frac{\left((1-x^C)+z x^C\right)^N}{(1-x)^N}&=&[x^B]\frac{1}{(1-x)^N}\sum_{D\geq K}\binom{N}{D}x^{CD}(1-x^C)^{N-D}\\&=&\sum_{D\geq K}\binom{N}{D}[x^{B-CD}]\frac{(1-x^C)^{N-D}}{(1-x)^N}\\&=&\color{red}{\sum_{D\geq K}\binom{N}{D}\sum_{h=0}^{N-D}\binom{N-D}{h}(-1)^h\binom{N+B-CD-Ch-1}{N-1}}, \end{eqnarray*}$$

rather ugly.

Comment: Creates impressive formulas. The trick seems to be coming up with a generating function, where expansion results in summation processes similar to the wanted summations. I wonder how much effort it takes to get a bit into it.

Comment: @mvw: not so much, once one may learn from the best: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: Wow, I wanted to remark that the originality of its title is akin to the "A=B" book, and now I see it is from the same author. Sad to see he passed.

Comment: This is interesting. Just give me a minute to work through it :)

Comment: For B = 6, N = 3, C = 2, K = 2 your solution gives -22 where as the correct answer is 16. I posted this is the question.

Comment: @nickponline: with that parameters I get $h_B(z)=12 z + 15 z^2 + z^3$, from which the correct answer $15+1=16$. Maybe I made some mistake in converting that number in a sum of binomial coefficients, but the method without the last formula seems to work.

Comment: I think I follow your logic @JackD'Aurizio I'm just trying to find the mistake in the last formula.

Comment: @nickponline: oh, wait, I got it. Here I am using the convention that $\binom{a}{b}$ equals zero if $a<b$, but that is not universal, for instance Mathematica returns $-4$ for $\binom{-2}{3}$. That makes sense if we think to $\binom{a}{b}$ as a polynomial with degree $b$ in the $a$ variable, but here I am using the "counting definition" of the binomial coefficient.

Comment: @nickponline: the Mathematica command $$\sum _{E=2}^3 \text{Binomial}[3,E]\sum _{h=0}^{3-E} \text{Binomial}[3-E,h](-1){}^{\wedge}h \text{Binomial}[3+6-2 E-2 h-1,2]\text{HeavisideTheta}[6-2 E-2 h+1/2]$$ returns the right answer, $16$. I modified the definition of the binomial coefficient in order to have $\binom{a}{b}=0$ for $a<b$.

Comment: Thank you this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could move to new variables $x_i' = x_i - C \ge 0$ for the variables with the minimum value $C$. Then the equation transforms to
$$
x'_1 + \ldots x'_K + x_{K+1} + \ldots x_N = B - K \, C
$$
assuming <strike>WLOG</strike> GRUMBL MUMBL that those variables are the first $K$ ones.

This is a problem of the form
$$
n_1 + \ldots + n_N = n \quad (n_i \ge 0) \quad (*)
$$
which is related to [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) from combinatorics. A composition of $n$ is a way to write $n$ as sum of integers $n_i \ge 1$. We need weak composition of $n$, which allows terms $n_i \ge 0$, but only those which have $N$ terms. The number of compositions of $n$ into $N$ parts is $\binom{n-1}{N-1}$, the number of weak compositions of $n$ into $N$ parts follows from looking at the number of compositions of $n+N$ into $N$ parts (and subtracting $1$ for each of the $N$ parts on both sides), so equation $(*)$ has
$$
\binom{n+N-1}{N-1} = \binom{B-K\,C+N-1}{N-1}
$$
solutions.

Your example turns into
$$
x'_1 + x'_2 + x_3 = 5-2\cdot 2 = 1
$$
and should have $\binom{1+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{3}{2}=3!/(2!1!)=3$ solutions.
We find
$$
(x'_1, x'_2, x_3) \to (x_1, x_2, x_3) \\
(1,0,0) \to (3,2,0) \\
(0,1,0) \to (2,3,0) \\
(0,0,1) \to (2,2,1)
$$
The found solution in $x'_i$ has then to be transformed back via $x_i = x'_i + C$, see the right side above.

**Update:**
The above assumed the constraints were at fixed positions and attached the constraints $x_i \ge C$ to the variables $1$ to $K$.
It should be clear that if the constraints were assigned to a different subset of variables indexed by $I = \{ I_1, \ldots, I_K \} \subset \{1, \ldots, N \}$ we end up with the same solutions, albeit permutated, along to the permutation of the indices.

E.g. for the example we have:
$$
(x_1, x'_2, x_3') \to (x_1, x_2, x_3) \\
(1,0,0) \to (1,2,2) \\
(0,1,0) \to (0,3,2) \\
(0,0,1) \to (0,2,3)
$$
and
$$
(x_1', x_2, x_3') \to (x_1, x_2, x_3) \\
(1,0,0) \to (3,0,2) \\
(0,1,0) \to (2,1,2) \\
(0,0,1) \to (2,0,3)
$$
These are all $9$ solutions.

What we need here are [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations), as we are interested only in the chosen subset, not in what order the elements were chosen. 
There are $\binom{N}{K}$ $K$-combinations from a set of $N$ elements.

Note: This part needs $C \ge 1$, otherwise the resulting tuples are not distinct. There might be further conditions to watch, to justify this factor, see the comments.

**Result:**

There should be
$$
\binom{N}{K} \binom{B-K\,C +N-1}{N-1}
$$
solutions to the original problem. Caution: This might degrade to an upper bound, see the comments.

Comment: But the variables are different, no? So going with $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ with $2$ of them greater than $2$ and sum equals to 5, the answers (2, 2, 1) and (1, 2, 2) are different. And you can't just multiply the whole thing by ${n \choose k}$ since that will certainly cause double-counting in situations where $B - KC > C$.

Comment: I'm saying your answer is not taking into account **order**, essentially. You're missing many solutions, namely (1, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 0, 3), (3, 0, 2).

Comment: And you may be tempted to multiply your number by ${n \choose k}$ but this leads to double-counting (not in this particular situation, since $B - KC < C$.

Comment: Agreed. The WLOG needs to be explained more... though this might be in a right direction.

Comment: @Soke Despite the two warnings I could not resist :-) Do you have a nice example which can illustrate the problem? I need a break and try later to understand, why you deem $B - KC$ vs $C$ critical.

Comment: I think this does give a correct upper bound.  (For n=5, C=4, K=2, B=12, I believe the number of solutions is 680.)

Comment: @user84413: I also get $680$ through my approach, described below. So my horrible formula simplifies a lot, I bet.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for letting me know; and I am interested to see that this can be done with generating functions.

Comment: For B = 6, N = 3, C = 2, K = 2 your solution gives 18 where as the correct answer is 16. I posted this is the question. Also this is within the B-KC <= C so should not double count.

Comment: Do not rule out that your code might be buggy. :-) I try again tomorrow.