# What is an example simillar with $\#A+\#B=\#(A\cup B) + \#(A\cap B)$?

Tags: education

I already know simillar form of $\#A+\#B=\#(A\cup B) + \#(A\cap B)$ holds with finite dimensional $F$-vector spaces(not clear with infinite dimensional) like this form...

$$
\dim V+\dim W=\dim(V+W)+\dim(V\cap W)
$$

which is corollaty of **Second Isomorphism Theorem**.

I'm curious about this form... Are there exists simillar form or fomulae at any other parts?(such as group theory... or etc.)

Comment: $mn=\gcd(m,n){\rm lcm}(m,n)$.

Comment: Probability and measures, e.g. $\#=P$, and the identify follows from the axioms of a measure.

Comment: Related $\;-\;$ [A general "inclusion-exclusion principle" / Formulas like $\inf(a,b)\sup(a,b)=ab$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232363/a-general-inclusion-exclusion-principle-formulas-like-infa-b-supa-b-ab/).