# Probability of $l$ red columns when all $m$ rows have $k$ red and $n-k$ white balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given:

- There are $m$ rows of balls.
- Each row has $k$ red balls and $n-k$ white balls, randomly placed.

With what probability do there exist $l$ totally red collumns?

[image: visual aid]

**Update:** The only thing I found out is the total number of possibilities:

$${n\choose k}^m$$

Comment: Remark: please show your attempts. Hint: start by calculating the total number of outcomes.

Comment: @maxmilgram I only managed to calculate the total number of outcomes: ${n\choose k}^m$

Comment: There is no $l$ in your answer, which makes it highly suspicious.

Comment: For the first row we have no restrictions. Then we have ${k\choose l}$ options to choose the red columns. For all other rows $l$ spots are already filled with red marbles leaving $k-l$ marbles to be distributed among $n-l$ places. This should give ${n\choose k}{n-l\choose k-l}^{m-1}{k\choose l}$ positive outcomes.

Comment: @maxmilgram, thank you, it seems that you have calculated the outcomes for which there exists *at least* $l$ red collumns, right?

Comment: You are completely right!

Comment: Do you want the probability that there are _at least_ $\ell$ red columns, or _exactly_ $\ell$ red columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** I think the easiest way is to use the generalized principle of inclusion exclusion. Specifically, if there are several events $E_1,E_2,\dots,E_n$, and we let $X$ denote the number of these events which occur, then
$$
P(X\ge \ell) = \sum_{j=\ell }^n (-1)^{j-\ell}\binom{j-1}{\ell-1}\sum_{S\subseteq [n],|S|=j} P(E_S)\tag 1
$$
where $S$ ranges over all subsets of $[n]\stackrel{\text{def}}=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of size $j$, and $E_S=\bigcap_{i\in S}E_i$.

Specifically, $E_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ column is all red. Then $P(E_S)$ is the event that all columns in $S$ are red, which is not hard to compute. Plugging that answer into $(1)$, you get a summation formula for the probability that at least $\ell$ red columns exist.

Alternatively, the probability that exactly $\ell$ columns are red is 
$$
P(X=\ell) = \sum_{j=\ell }^n (-1)^{j-\ell}\binom{j}{\ell}\sum_{S\subseteq [n],|S|=j} P(E_S)\tag 2
$$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516/177399) for a proof of $(2)$, from which you can derive $(1)$ by summing (after applying Pascal's identity, there will be a telescopic sum).

Comment: Thank you! $P(E_S)={n-|S|\choose k-|S|}^m/{n\choose k}^m$ and $|\{S\subseteq[n]:|S|=j\}|={n\choose j}$, which gives $P(X\geq\ell)=\sum_{j=\ell}^n(-1)^{j-\ell}{j-1\choose\ell-1}{n\choose j}{n-j\choose k-j}^m/{n\choose k}^m$. This is not simplifyable by Mathematica and not the same as the solution given by maxmilgram: ${n\choose k}{n-\ell\choose k-\ell}^{m-1}{k\choose \ell}/{n\choose k}^m$.

Comment: @Carucel Indeed, maxmilgram's answer is incorrect. Their answer is the first summand of my answer, indicating they are not correcting for overcounting; their answer overcounts cases where there are more than $\ell$ red columns, as they are not uniquely represented by choosing $\ell$ red columns, then choosing the rest of the entries arbitrarily.