# How to use Inclusion Exclusion On Dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Here is the question

> Suppose we roll 5 standard fair dice and sum the upfaces of the
> largest 3 values showing. Find the probability that the sum is
> 18.

I tried an easier version of this question using Inclusion Exclusion and it worked

> Suppose we roll 3 standard fair dice and sum the upface of the largest value showing. Find the probability that the sum is 6.

$\frac{1}{6}\cdot3-\frac{1}{6}^{2}\cdot3+\frac{1}{6}^{3}$

So first we count getting at least one six and multiply by 3 choose 1, then subtract getting two sixes and mutliply by 3 choose 2, and the finally add back getting 3. I think this only works because the PIE is revolving around only one die.

Here is me applying the same logic but to at least 3 out 5, instead of at least 1 out of 3.

$\frac{1}{6}^{3}\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,3\right)-\frac{1}{6}^{4}\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,4\right)+\frac{1}{6^{5}}$

I calculated the right answer a different way using cases, so I know this answer is wrong and is overcounting.

Comment: Why not just compute the probability that you get at least three $6's$?

Comment: Can yuu give us an example? I do not understand the rules to count.

Comment: $\frac{5^{2}\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,3\right)}{6^{5}}+\frac{5\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,4\right)}{6^{5}}+\frac{1}{6^{5}}$

@callculus42 This is by cases (3  6s, 4 6s, 5 6s), I guess this is fine. I just want to know how the PIE works in a case like this.

Comment: I mean your simplified exercise. If you roll 5,2,4 what would be the outcome?

Comment: 5,2,4 you choose the largest one, and that is 5. But 5 is not 6 so it would not count as a successful case. Basically, we look for cases with at least one 6. Does that explain it?

Comment: @Marko Yes, it does.

Comment: @Marko The application of the PIE does not make sense here, IMHO. In the second case you should calculate $P(X\geq 1) =P(X= 1)+P(X= 2)+P(X= 3)  $, where $X$ is the number of 6's on the upfaces of the three dice.

Comment: The principle of inclusion exclusion gives the probability of _at least one_ event happening, but you want the probability of rolling _at least three_ sixes. Therefore, you need the [generalized PIE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362516/177399).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm back a month later and I figured it out.

Basically rewording the first small question.

> What is the probability we get at least one six, if we roll $3$ dice?

Rewording the more complex.

> What is the probability we get at least three sixes if we roll $5$ dice?

Mike Earnest linked the generalized PIE, which was a little hard to understand. So I will try to explain it here a little more gently.

**--- Second questions revised and answered.**

$$\frac{1}{6^{3}}\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,3\right)\ -\ \frac{1}{6^{4}}\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,4\right)+\frac{1}{6^{5}}$$

So why didn't this work with less than 3?

Because we counted wrong!

We first add the at least three $6$-face-up subsets, once for each one. But how many times did we add the at least $4$ $6$-face-up subsets?

Well for each $4$ there are $\operatorname{nCr}\left(4,3\right)$ subsets of $3$ within it, so we we did not add twice like my previous attempt tries. We added it $4$ times! So we need to subtract it $3$ times!

Well ok, how about the all $5$ subset.

Well we know we added it 10 times for the first case, and now we are going to subtract it $\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,4\right)\cdot3$ times. So we will get a total of $10-15 = -5$ counts of the $5$ six set, so we need to add it back $6$ times!

So what we wanted was
$\frac{1}{6^{3}}\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,3\right)\ -\ \frac{1}{6^{4}}\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(5,4\right)\cdot3+\frac{1}{6^{5}}\cdot6$

Which is around **$3.5\%$**.