# How many ways can you list numbers $1,2,3,...,n$ so that no number $i$ is in its $ith$ place on the list?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can you list numbers $1,2,3,...,n$ so that no number $i$ is in its $ith$ place on the list?

For example, $1,3,2,4$ is not a valid list since $1$ is in $1st$ place.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  Thanks for quick response, haven't actually done combinatronics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement you just proposed is just no. of dearrangement, which is well Known.Look here for details[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166378/de-arrangement-in-permutation-and-combination)