# Why does the expansion of $e^x$ appear to arise in the formula for derangement of $n$ things $D_{n}=n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, derangements

I was recently toying with Wolfram|Alpha with the expansion of $e^x$ and I noticed a strange thing. On substituting $x=-1$ (if it is allowed), I get on the RHS the strange looking infinite expression of $$e^{-1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\ldots+(-1)^n\frac{1}{n!}+\ldots\right)$$
(ignoring for the time being all terms after ${n+1}^{th}$ term), which I find very similar to the formula I learned for the number of derangements of $n$ things (if we ignore the *infinite nature* of the expansion of $e^x$ and just look at the first $n+1$ terms for some time) $$D_n=n!\left(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\ldots+(-1)^n\frac{1}{n!}\right)$$
So is this similarity just a coincidence? Or are they related in any way whatsoever? Because I am not able to relate them in any way; after all, $e$ and derangements in combinatorics seem like two very different topics to me. But their similarity is very striking... Even for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is **very** heuristic:

The probability that a given one of the $n$ things is not at his proper place is $1-{1\over n}$. Assuming that the $n$ things are placed properly or improperly independently of each other the probability that all things are improperly placed computes to
$$\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n\doteq{1\over e}\ .$$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Your equality holds when $n\to\infty$ only. So in general it is wrong to make such a statement. Say $n=2,3,4,5,6$ and then what you say is not right.

Comment: @Aniket: It is a folklore fact that even for moderate $n$ the probability in question is $\doteq{1\over e}$ with high accuracy. I just gave a bogus "proof" for this that circumvents the combinatorics..

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Perhaps I didn't get you before.Thanks for clarifying. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's from the generating function theory and the fact that we have a nice recursion formula for derangements: $d_{n+1} = n(d_n + d_{n-1})$ for $n \ge 1$. For any counting problem like this where the answer is $d_n$ for $n$ objects, we can define a formal exponential generating function $D(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ (there is also a normal generating function without the $n!$ term).

Know we can try to determine the function $D(x)$ from the recursion, and from that get the coefficients $d_n$, this is worked out very nicely in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/240369/4280), where you will see the connection.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of stuff to say here. First, here is one way of interpreting the result: asymptotically, the probability that a random permutation is a derangement is $e^{-1}$. There are a lot of related claims you can write down. Here are two:

- For fixed $k$, asymptotically, the probability that a random permutation has exactly $k$ fixed points is $\frac{e^{-1}}{k!}$.
- For fixed $k$, asymptoically, the probability that a random permutation has no $k$-cycles is $e^{- \frac{1}{k}}$.

So basically there's a lot of $e$ business going on. My preferred way to think about all this is via a very large and beautiful generating function called the exponential formula, which you can read about [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/gila-v-the-polya-enumeration-theorem-and-applications/) and [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/gila-vi-the-cycle-index-polynomials-of-the-symmetric-groups/). It describes the cycle types of all permutations simultaneously, and specializing it in various ways extracts various information about cycle types. See, for example, [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/short-cycles-in-random-permutations/).