# Formula for an equation

Tags: functions

Is there any formula for ${(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}^{2^n}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using well-known [Binomial Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html), $(a+b)^m=\sum_{0\le r\le m}\binom m ra^{m-r}b^r$ where $m$ is a positive integer.

Put $a=1,b=-\frac1{2^n},m =2^n$ we shall get the required expansion.

Now we know from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271940/series-for-frac-1e/271989#271989), $$\lim_{m\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m=e\implies \lim_{m\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1m\right)^{mn}=e^n$$

Answer (score 1):

The notation as it is, As far as I know, has no simpler expression.

However, note that,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)}^{2^n}=\frac{1}{e}$$ which you can prove.

**Added :** It is not so difficult to prove it. Just substitute $x=2^n$ and note that $x\rightarrow \infty $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Also note that:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{x}\right)^x=e^{-1}$$

Comment: Can you please write the main idea behind the prove?