# Given $n$ distinct elements, what is the number of different combinations with unique order?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, given $1,2,3$, we have 15 combinations:

$1,2,3,12,13,21,23,31,32,123,132,213,231,312,321$.

I have the formula $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}*k!$ which can be simplified to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

I am wondering whether or not this formula can be further simplified...?

Comment: With respect to the title of your question, you forgot the empty combination ($0$ elements).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n\ge1$, your sum is equal to
$$
\lfloor n!e-1\rfloor
$$
This is because
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}\\
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}-n!\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k!}\\
&=n!e-1-\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}-\dots
\end{align}
$$
and since $\frac1n=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^3}+\dots\gt\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\dots$
$$
n!e-1-\frac1n\lt\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\lt n!e-1-\frac1{n+1}
$$

---

**Examples**

For $n=2$, this gives $\lfloor5.43656365691809-1\rfloor=4$.
For $n=3$, this gives $\lfloor16.3096909707543-1\rfloor=15$.
For $n=4$, this gives $\lfloor65.2387638830171-1\rfloor=64$.

Comment: Thanks. I think you forgot the (possibly trivial for you) conversion from $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ to $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{k!}$

Comment: This is cool! The floor function reminds me of [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements). +1

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Indeed! I gave [an answer about derangements](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/83472) a while ago. In that case, it is the integer closest to $\frac{n!}{e}$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the sum you wrote corresponds to the number of combinations in lists like the one you wrote out.

I think you're looking for $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}$$

---

This is the sum of the elements in the $(n+1)^\text{th}$ row of [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), minus one. This is equal to $$2^{n+1}-1$$.

For example, when $n=3$, this gives $2^4-1 = 15$.

---

EDIT: **This answer is incorrect (see comments).**

Comment: For $n=3$, your formula yields $3+3+1=7$, and it's not what I'm looking for in any case. Pascal Triangle gives you the number of permutations, where the order of elements is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I edited my answer. I meant row number $n+1$. So for $n=3$, we have $4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 15$. I think it is what you're looking for :)

Comment: **Example**: For $n=10$, we can use the more convenient formula $2^{n+1} -1$ to get $2047$ as the number of combinations.

Comment: For $n=2$ your this would give $7$, whereas the correct answer is $4$ ($1, 2, 12, 21$)... Even conceptually, you give a formula that doesn't take permutations into account, and the $n+1$ comes from nowhere. It's just a coincidence that it gives the right result for $n=3$.

Comment: Given $1,2,3,4$, I have 64 combinations. Your formula yields 31. So I gave you a vote, but the answer is not correct.

Comment: This does not count what the question asks. This counts the number of ways to arrange $n$ objects and one blank. However, there are sometimes more than one blank in the arrangement that is requested in the question.

Comment: Yes, this is completely wrong. I edited the answer to say that. Thanks for noting that it was a simple coincidence that it worked for $n=3$ ... not sure what I was thinking.