# 4 People Gift Exchange

Tags: permutations

4 people are exchanging gifts. How many combinations are there so that no one receives their own gift?
I tried this problem myself, and got 3!. My friends told me that it's 9.

I got 3! because I thought:

Person A: Has 3 options for gifts (excluding his own)
Person B: Has 2 options for gifts (excluding his own, and the one taken)
Person C: Has 1 option for a gift (excluding his own, the two taken)
Person D: Has 1 option for a gift (excluding the 3 taken)

So I deduced that the answer would be 3!

But my friends did it by hand and got 9, one of them showed me this chart:

**A   B   C   D**

B   A   D   C

B   C   D   A

B   D   A   C

The chart is all the possibilities if A takes gift B, and he told me to repeat it 3 times for all other gifts that A could take→ 3 + 3 + 3 = 9

Is there an elegant solution to this problem? Could someone explain to me why my method neglects to include the other 3 options.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I read «combinatronics» and I came to see what it was. Color me disappointed!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what it's called. I just saw this problem online and wanted to solve it.

Comment: You are write that A has 3 choices but one choice is gift B and, in that one case, if B goes next she has 3 and not two choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the set of $4$ elements. A derangement is a permutation in which no element is left unmoved. There are three approaches to computing derangements in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83472). One method gives
$$
4!\left(\frac1{0!}-\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}\right)=9
$$