# Let $A= { x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 ,x_5 }$ , $B = { y_1 , y_2 , y_3 , y_4 , y_5 }$ , then find the number of one-one functions from $A$ to $B$ such that

Tags: functions, permutations, combinations

Let $A= \{ x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 ,x_5 \}$ , $B = \{ y_1 , y_2 , y_3 , y_4 , y_5 \}$ , then find the number of one-one functions from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(x_i) \ne {y_i}$ where $i = 1,2,3,4,5$ .

So we know that number of one-one functions are $nPm$ where $m$ and $n$ elements are in sets $A$ and $B$ . But in this question $f(x_i) \ne {y_i}$ so i tried to exclude them from total number of one-one function . But this will go very lengthy . I know we can do this by permutation and combination but i studied it a long time ago and do not remember all the concepts clearly .

Comment: How many ways can you permute $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

Comment: Related: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/i-have-a-problem-understanding-the-proof-of-rencontres-numbers-derangements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K(n)$ be the number of one-to-one maps  $ m: \{ 1, 2, \ldots n \} \leftrightarrow
\{ 1, 2, \ldots n \}$ such that for all $i\leq n$, $m(i) \neq i$.

(The question wishes to find $K(5)$.)

Let  $J(n)$ be the number of one-to-one maps  $ m: \{ 1, 2, \ldots n \} \leftrightarrow
\{ 1, 2, \ldots n \}$ such that for some (at least one) $i\leq n$, $m(i) = i$.

And let $P(n)$ be the number of one-to-one maps  $ m: \{ 1, 2, \ldots n \} \leftrightarrow
\{ 1, 2, \ldots n \}$.
$$
P(n) = n! =  K(n) + J(n) $$

Then $K(1) = 0$, $J(1) = 1$, and for all $n>1$:

$$ J(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} K(n-k) +1\\
K(n) = n! - J(n)
$$
To explain that first equation in words, "to end up with one or more matches, you pick the number of matches ($k$) you want to have, then pick the identities of those $k$ matches among the $n$ possibilities, then find some arrangement of the remaining $n-k$ numbers that gives you no more matches."  The one at the end corresponds to choosing to match all $n$ numbers (the identity map); we could equally well instead have extended the sum to $k=n$ if we defined $K(0) = 1$.

Then $$
\begin{array}{ccc}
n&J(n) & K(n) \\ 
\hline
1 & 1 & 1!-1 = 0\\
2 & \binom{2}{1} 0 + 1 = 1 & 2!-1 = 1 \\
3 & \binom{3}{1} 2 + \binom{3}{2} 0+ 1 = 4 & 3!-4 = 2 \\
4 & \binom{4}{1} 2 + \binom{4}{2} 1+ \binom{4}{3} 0+ 1 = 15 & 4!-15 = 9 \\
5 & \binom{5}{1} 9 + \binom{5}{2} 2+ \binom{5}{3} 1+ 1 = 76 & 5!-76 = 44 \\
\end{array}
$$

THe $K(n)$ are called *derangement numbers*, and as you see, $K(5) = 44$.

Comment: Just remembered i did another question with same type you did earlier when i studied Permutation and combination . Great Explanation . Thanks!

Comment: @SethRollins Usually these are called $D_n$ (_derangement numbers_) and a nice closed form is
$$D_n = \left[ \frac{n!}e \right]$$
Where $[\cdot]$ denotes the nearest-integer function (round).

Answer (score 3):

> 44 mappings

Begin with $5!$ possible mappings.

Now, subtract out all mappings with at least one fixed point. There will be $5 \cdot 4!$ of these.

In doing this, mappings with two fixed points were subtracted twice, so we add them back in. There are $ \binom{5}{2} \cdot 3!$ options here.

Similarly, we've now added in mappings with 3 fixed points too many times, so we subtract those back out. There are $ \binom{5}{3} \cdot 2!$ of those.

We continue this addition and subtraction (formally, the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion - similar to counting cases in Venn diagrams) until finally we have the correct number of mappings:

> $$ 5! - 5 \cdot 4! + 10 \cdot 3! - 10 \cdot 2! + 5 \cdot 1! - 1 = 120 - 120 + 60 - 20 + 5 - 1 = \textbf{44}.$$

Comment: I hope everything here is formatted well enough and the level of the explanation is ok. As you can tell from my reputation points, I'm pretty new here. I'm pretty sure this is the first time I've posted anything!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. Exclude from the permutation the following:

1. Maps that fix five elements, or maps fix four elements and permute one; We can see these are just the identity.

Let's say we map each element $12345$ from $A$ to $B$ in the order: $12345$. This is the only way for this case.

2. Maps that fix three elements and permute two; How many are there?

For example, the order of set $B$ could be: 
$$12354 (\text{ fix }123), 15342 (\text{ fix } 134), \dots$$

3. Maps that fix two elements and permute three; These have to be cycles on the three; How many are there?

For example, fix $12$, cycle on $345$, you can get
$$12453, 12534$$

If they are not cycle, you will have to fix another element, which will be the same as case 2 or 1.

Continue with this pattern, you should be able to find the numbers.

Comment: Sorry but could not get you , can you explain by one example ?

Comment: @SethRollins: Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Permutations without fixed points are called derangements. The number of derangements of an $n$-element set is also called the subfactorial of $n$, written $!n$, and [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) gives recursion equations for $!n$, using which you will find that $!5 = 44$. See also http://oeis.org/A000166.