# Solution to a recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> Set $F_k(x) := \sum_{n\geq k} S(n,k)x^n$. Prove that $$F_1(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}, \space \space \space F_2(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)(1-2x)} $$
>
> Furthermore, show that the function $F_k(x)$ satisfy the recurrence relation $$F_k(x) = \frac{x}{1-kx}F_{k-1}(x)$$ and solve this recurrence.

Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Comment: @flawr Stirling number of the second kind. And I don't know even how to attack the problem.

Comment: Do you know about generating functions? If not it might be still feasible but perhpas somewhat more difficult. I recomment [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) a great introduction to generating functions. PS: I just noticed that you can find this exact example in the mentioned book at about page 19.

Comment: There is an extensive discussion of this at the following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422006/).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the notation $n\brace k$ for your $S(n,k)$. The first step is to observe that ${n\brace 1}=1$ for $n\ge 1$: there is only one partition of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into just one part. Thus,

$$F_1(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}{n\brace 1}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 1}x^n=x\sum_{n\ge 1}x^{n-1}=x\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}\;.$$

To get $F_2(x)$, we need to figure out what $n\brace 2$ is. Suppose that we partition $[n]$ into two non-empty parts. One of the parts must contain the number $n$; call that part $A$ and the other part $B$. What can the rest of $A$ look like? It can’t be all of $[n-1]$, since then $B$ would be empty, but it can be any other subset of $[n-1]$. Since $[n-1]$ has $2^{n-1}$ subsets, there are $2^{n-1}-1$ possible choices for the rest of $A$ and hence for a $2$-part partition of $[n]$. Thus, ${n\brace 2}=2^{n-1}-1$ for $n\ge 2$, and

$$\begin{align*}
F_2(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 2}{n\brace 2}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 2}\left(2^{n-1}-1\right)x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 2}2^{n-1}x^n-\sum_{n\ge 2}x^n\\
&=2x^2\sum_{n\ge 0}(2x)^n-x^2\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\\
&=\frac{2x^2}{1-2x}-\frac{x^2}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{2x^2(1-x)-x^2(1-2x)}{(1-x)(1-2x)}\\
&=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)(1-2x)}\;.
\end{align*}$$

At this point we want the standard [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation) satisfied by the Stirling numbers of the second kind,

$${n\brace k}=k{{n-1}\brace k}+{{n-1}\brace{k-1}}\;,$$

substituting it into the definition of $F_k(x)$:

$$\begin{align*}
F_k(x)&=\sum_{n\ge k}{n\brace k}x^n\\
&=k\sum_{n\ge k}{{n-1}\brace k}x^n+\sum_{n\ge k}{{n-1}\brace{k-1}}x^n\\
&=kx\sum_{n\ge k-1}{n\brace k}x^n+x\sum_{n\ge k-1}{n\brace{k-1}}x^n\\
&=kxF_k(x)+xF_{k-1}(x)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now just solve for $F_k(x)$ in terms of $F_{k-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the good answer. If you are free can you take a look at the following problem. There seems to be an answer, but I really don't understand anything from that answer. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528709/proving-recurrence-relation-on-the-cardinal-of-the-derangements

Comment: How did you get the recurrence relation formula (${n\brace k}=k{{n-1}\brace k}+{{n-1}\brace{k-1}}\;$) that you have written from the standard formula in Wikipedia, cause it seems a bit different, clearly you have done some algebraic manipulation but I cannot see it.

Comment: @terett: I simply decreased the upper number by $1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Isn't that kind of operation problem? Because now we try to partition $n-1$ element set into $k-1$-partition, instead of the original $n$ element set, so we have one less element I see.

Comment: @terett: No, it’s not a problem at all. It’s no different in principle from taking a recurrence $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$ and rewriting it as $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. If you prefer, you can think of it as a substitution. Let $m=n+1$; then the recurrence in Wikipedia becomes ${m\brace k}=k{{m-1}\brace k}+{m\brace{k-1}}$. Now rename $m$ to $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I started studying higher combinatorics, but because I had never seen this stuff apart from binomial coefficients, and permutations. I still don't get all the concepts. I understood somehow the Stirling numbers, but I don't see exactly what's their relation with generating functions. But, I guess this can be another question in Math.SE.

Comment: @terett: You’re welcome. Yes, that would be better as a separate question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, and I already did. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532420/whats-the-relation-between-stirling-numbers-and-the-generating-functions

Comment: @portal: I’ve added an answer to the question that you asked about.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you please help me with this problem? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534243/solving-the-recurrence-a-n1-a-nn12-a-0-1-using-generating-functions