# Identities about Bell numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers, bell-numbers

> The $n$-th Bell number equals the number of set partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We set $B_0 := 1$. Prove the following identities: $$B_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}S_{n,k} \qquad and \qquad B_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}B_k$$

I don't exactly know what Bell numbers are. I checked their definition, it was something like the number of partitions, but it was a bit vague to me. I still don't get what's its connection to Stirling numbers and binomial coefficient. Any ideas with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. $B_n$ is the number of partitions of $[n]$ into any number of parts; $S_{n,k}$ is the number of partitions of $[n]$ into exactly $k$ parts.

For the second part of the question, suppose that you have a partition of $[n+1]$. One of its parts must contain the number $n+1$; call that part $P$. Let $k=|[n+1]\setminus P|$. Now think about these questions:

- What are the possible values of $k$?
- How many ways are there to choose $k$ elements other than $n+1$?
- How many partitions of $k$ elements are there?

Comment: For the first part, it is clear that we need to sum over all possible $k$-partition of $[n]$ in order to get $B_n$, cause as you explained, it is partition of $[n]$ into any number of parts. I got the idea, but apart from the words, how can I prove it mathematically? On the other hand, for the second part, I didn't exactly get the part $k=|[n+1]\setminus P|$, I mean the meaning of it. Is $k = n+1 - |P|$? Which I guess clearly corresponds to the sum symbol...

Comment: ...how many ways are there to choose $k$ elements other than $n+1$, so if we have chosen $n+1$the element, we have $n$ remaining so we have $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose them. And your last question, how many partitions of $k$ elements are there is exactly $B_k$ from the definition of Bell numbers. Though, I'm having difficulty in putting all of this into a formal mathematical proof.

Comment: @portal: The proof of the first part mostly *is* words, a combination of what I wrote and what you just wrote. \\ Yes, $k=n+1-|P|$, but I wrote it the way I did to emphasize that what it’s counting is what’s left of $[n+1]$ after the set $P$ is removed. You’ve answered the questions correctly. The idea is that every partition of $[n+1]$ has a part $P$ that contains $n+1$, and the remaining parts form a partition of $[n+1]\setminus P$. We can count the partitions of $[n+1]$ by first counting the ways to choose a subset $Q$ of $[n]$, setting $P=[n+1]\setminus Q$, and counting the ways to ...

Comment: ... partition $Q$. Try to match that description up with the pieces of the formula.

Comment: I got confused with that $Q$.  You said "by first counting the ways to choose a subset $Q$ of $[n]$", this is the $\binom{n}{k}$. And "counting the ways to partition $Q$" is clearly $B_k$. So, we go over the sum and count, we can have a part with $[n]$ which includes $n+1$, and then we are left with part of $k = 1$, then $k = 2$, and we have part with $[n-1]$ that includes $n+1$, and so on and so on, until we reach a partition of $[1]$ which is composed of only $n+1$, and on the other side we have a partition of $k = n$, right?

Comment: @portal: You’re making it too complicated. Let’s try this. To make a partition of $[n+1]$, one way is to start by choosing the part that contains $n+1$, and one way to do **that** is to start by choosing the elements of $[n+1]$ that are *not* in the same part as $n+1$; that’s the set that I called $Q$, and it must be a subset of $[n]$. In fact it can be *any* subset of $[n]$. Now we divide up the subsets of $[n]$ according to their sizes. For each size $k$ from $0$ through $n$ there are $\binom{n}k$ subsets of $[n]$ that could be $Q$, and there are $B_k$ partitions of each of those subsets ...

Comment: ... of $[n]$, so each $k$ accounts for $\binom{n}kB_k$ partitions of $[n+1]$.

Comment: Okay, now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: When you have time, can you take a look at the following problem, I see it is also in one of my problem sets. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528970/solution-to-a-recurrence-relation/1529077

Comment: @portal: You’re welcome! Yes, I’ll take a look at the other problem.