# What does it mean for a bijection to have no fixed point?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Say $f(n)$ is number of bijections in a set of $n$ elements without a fixed point.  What would this mean?  I know that a bijection means that each element in one set is paired with exactly one element in another set.  But what does without a fixed point mean?

Comment: As an aside, a bijection with no fixed points is referred to as a [Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  The number of derangements on a set with $n$ elements is often denoted as $!n$ or $D_n$ or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this piece of knowledge!

Comment: It means f(x) is never equal to x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fixed point of a function $f:X\to X$ is an element $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=x$.

For instance, if $X=\{1,2,3\}$, then the function defined by $f(1)=1,f(2)=3,f(3)=2$ has $1$ as a fixed point, while the function $g(1)=2,g(2)=3,g(3)=1$ has no fixed points.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A fixed point is of the form $f(n) = n$. It means that $f$ fixes the "location" of $n$. If there are no fixed points, then every element in the set is "moved".

Answer (score 0):

Yet another point of view.

Consider the classical association of a permutation on $n$ objects with its matrix, for example:

$$\text{Permutation} \ \ \binom{1 \ 2 \ 3}{2 \ 3 \ 1} \ \ \ \text{is associated with} \ \ \ \pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}$$

Thus, clearly, a permutation without any fixed point (like the one above) is associated with permutation matrices having only zeros on their diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

A permutation of a set of $n$ elements that has no fixed point is called a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83472), it is shown that the number of derangements of a set of $n$ elements is
$$
\mathcal{D}_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
$$
which is the closest integer to $\dfrac{n!}e$ for $n\ge1$.