# Counting derangements on $n$ elements using recurrences?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find an expression for the number of permutations on $n$ elements with no fixed points. I know that this can be done using the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I am trying to do this another way.

First I derived a recurrence $F_n$ for the number of permutations on n elements. If we choose to send the number 1 to a specific number j, we can partition the collection of permutations that do this into two sets: (1) those that send j back to 1 and (2) those that don’t.

In (1) we’ve mapped 1 to j and j to 1, so what remains is to assign the numbers in {2, …, j-1, j+1,…, n} to numbers {2, …, j-1, j+1,…, n}, which is the number of permutations with no fixed points on n-2 elements, or $F_{n-2}$.

In (2), we’ve mapped 1 to j, but need to map the remaining numbers {2, …, n} to the numbers {1, …, j-1, j+1, n} in such a way that j does not map to 1; we can relabel 1 as j’, and now this reduces to permutations with no fixed points on n-1 elements, or $F_{n-1}$.

Since we have $(n-1)$ choices of j, this results in the recurrence $$F_n = (n-1)(F_{n-1} + F_{n-2})$$

To solve this recurrence I tried to use the method of generating functions, writing,

$F = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} F_{k}x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k-1)(F_{k-1} + F_{k-2})x^k =$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k-1)F_{k-1}x^k + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k-1)F_{k-2}x^k$

Then writing,

$x^2F’ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} kF_{k}x^{k+1} = \sum_{k=1 \to \infty} (k-1)F_{k-1}x^{k}$

$x^2(xF)’ = \sum_{k=0 \to \infty} (k+1)F_{k}x^{k+2} = \sum_{k=2 \to \infty} (k)F_{k-2}x^{k}$

Then,

$F = x^2F’ + x^2(xF)’ = x^2F’ + x^2[F + xF’] = x^2F’ + x^2F + x^3F’$

And so we have the differential equation,
$$F = [x^2/(1-x)]F’$$

I tried to solve this differential equation, and hopefully be able to find the power series expansion for the solution, so that I can equate its coefficients with $F_{k}$.

This is where things didn’t really work out — defining $F_{0} = 1$, I have the initial condition $F(0) = 1$. Wolfram Alpha gives the solution to this differential equation as:

$$\frac{C_1e^{-1/x}}{x}$$
which is not defined at 0.

If I could get a hint on how to proceed here I would appreciate it!

Comment: You may find robjohn's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/i-have-a-problem-understanding-the-proof-of-rencontres-numbers-derangements) helpful.

Comment: You would have better luck if you used an *exponential* generating function $\sum_{k\ge 0}F_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$ instead of your *ordinary* generating function.