# Inclusion-Exclusion Problem - derangement

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ be a natural number and $X$ a finite set with $n$
>   elements. Show that the number of permutations of $X$ such that *no* element stays in the same position is
>   $$n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}.$$

For instance, there are 6 = 3! permutations of 3 elements, but only 2 of them are permutations which fix *no* element. Similarly, there are 24 = 4! permutations of 4 elements, but only 9 which fix *no* element.

Comment: These permutations are *derangements*.

Comment: closely related to [I have a problem understanding the proof of Rencontres numbers (Derangements)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83380).

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.