# The behaviour of $\operatorname{Im}(!n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, pochhammer-symbol

What's going on with the behaviour of the subfactorial's imaginary part? Background: Out of curiosity I tried to construct some recurrence relations using the Pochhammer symbol and out of those came some subfactorials. For example:

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+(3)_n=a_n+3(3+1)(3+2)...(3+n-1).$$

Mathematica gave me:

$a_n$ = $1/2 (-1)^n$ **Gamma**[$n+3$] **Subfactorial**[$-n-3$]$-$**Subfactorial**[$-3$].

Not having seen seen negative subfactorials before I googled "negative subfactorial" or "subfactorial of negative numbers" and some similar phrases, which gave 0 hits. Here's a plot:

[image: plot]

I also plotted the Gamma function (just to have something to relate to). So, I don't understand the behaviour of the imaginary part. Looking closer at the values of $\operatorname{Im}(!n)$ it appears that

$$\sum _{n=-\infty}^0 \operatorname{Im}(!n)=-\frac{\pi}{e^2}.$$

Anyone who can shed some light on this? Some intuition? Better methods of visualization?

Comment: Just out of curiosity : how did you get the last result ? Interesting problem $\to +1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I found it through numerical calculations in Mathematica. It was clear that it was converging really fast so I thought it might be something _interesting_.

Comment: Years ago, I wrote [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83472) that outlined various approaches to Derangements. Prompted by your question, I have added a derivation of the Incomplete Gamma Function formula for $\mathcal{D}(n)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Mathematica* obviously defines subfactorial (cf. Eq. $(4)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html)) of an arbitrary complex number $s$ as
$$
!s=\frac{\Gamma(s+1,-1)}{e},\tag1
$$
where $\Gamma(s,z)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function. The expression for the
function for integer negative $s$ can be found [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4#E15) and reads for $z=-1$:
$$
\Gamma(-n,-1)
=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}\left[i\pi+\operatorname{Ei}(1)-e\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k!\right],\tag2
$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$ is the [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

Thus,
$$
\operatorname{Im}\; !(-n)=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1)!}\frac\pi e
$$
and the summation formula:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{Im}\; !(-n)=-\frac{\pi}{e^2}
$$
immediately follows.

Comment: I have added a derivation for the analytic continuation of $\mathcal{D}(n)$ evaluated at the negative integers to [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83472) mentioned above.