# Approximate the graph of $e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, graphing-functions, approximation

While solving the integrals related to $e^{x^2}$, we try to approximate it. My question is there some function of which the graph is approximately like that of $e^{x^2}$?

Comment: That depends on the interval for integration.

Comment: You have been around for more than a year. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the power series representation we have

$$e^{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}+...$$

Taking more terms will give a better and better approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series for $e^{x^2}$ is $$1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2} + O(x^6),$$ so that any function that you sum $1$ to an even power of $x$ will ressemble approximately the function you mention. Take a look at its behaviour in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28x%5E2%29).