# Evaluation of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{\text G(n)}≈ 3+\frac{\,_0\rm F_2(2,3;1)}2 $ with the Barnes G function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, constants

I thought this problem would be arbitrary, but is really easier to calculate than the inspiration for this question:

> [Evaluating $\sum\limits_{x=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{!x}$ in exact form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218525/evaluating-sum-limits-x-2-infty-frac1x-in-exact-form)

Now our problem will include the [**Barnes G$(n)$**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function), [K](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-function), [Hyperfactorial H$(n)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html),functions. It also has OEIS entry [A$287013$](https://oeis.org/A287013):

$$\sum_\Bbb N \frac 1{\text G(n)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\text G(n)}=\frac 1{\text G(1)}+ \frac 1{\text G(2)}+ \frac 1{\text G(3)}+ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac1{\text G(n)} =3+ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac1{\text G(n)}\\ =3+\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac{\text K(n)}{\Gamma^{n-1}(n)}=\sum\frac{\text H(n-1)}{\Gamma^{n-1}(n)}=3+\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac1{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k!}=3+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}\\ =3+\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac1{1!2!\cdots(n-2)!(n-1)!}= 3.5868345309364719014988474…$$

Here is a graph of our summand:
[image]

Now remember the definition of the [Regularized Generalized Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQRegularized/02/) with the [Pochhammer Symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html):

$$\,_p \mathrm{\tilde  F}_q(a_1,…,a_p;b_1,…,b_q;z)\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{k=0}\frac{\prod_{j=1}^p \left(a_j\right)_nz^k}{k!\prod_{j=1}^q\Gamma(k+b_j)}$$

Let’s try the following:

$$3+\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac1{1!2!\cdots(n-2)!(n-1)!}= 3+\frac1{1!2!\cdots}\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{(1)_n 1^n}{\cdots\Gamma(n-2)\Gamma(n-1)\Gamma(n-0)n!} $$

Therefore I conjecture that:

$$\sum_\Bbb N \frac1{\text G(x)}= 3+\,_1 \rm{\tilde  F}_q(1;…,-1,0;1)$$

but how would I put $$3+\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac1{1!2!\cdots(n-2)!(n-1)!}$$ into closed form as the “$n-1$” amount of factorials would be a pain to evaluate in the sum? **A closed form is optional, so alternate forms are appreciated** Please correct me and give me feedback!

Actually, our conjecture is suppported by [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hypergeometricpfqregularized%28%7B1%7D%2C%7B-2%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C1%29):

$$3+\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac1{\text G(n)}≈3+\,_1\rm{\tilde F}_3(1;-2,-1,0;1)=3+\,_1\rm{\tilde F}_3(1;-3,-2,-1;1)\mathop=^{N\in\Bbb N }3+\,_1\rm{\tilde F}_3(1;N-2,N-1,N;1)= 3+\frac{\,_0\rm F_2(2,3;1)}2= 3.5868639104823…$$

It is also possible to write the following using [**this computation**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+-%28floor%28x%29+%281%2F2+%281+-+2+x+%2B+log%282+%CF%80%29%29+%2B+%28-1+%2B+x%29+polygamma%280%2C+x%29%29%29%2FBarnesG%28x%29+from+1+to+10) and the [Digamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\text G(x)}=-\int_1^\infty\lfloor x\rfloor d\left(\frac1{\text G(x)}\right)= \frac{\ln(2\pi)+1}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\text G(x)}dx-\int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor x}{\text G(x)}dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor xψ(x)}{\text G(x)}dx-\int_1^\infty\frac{\lfloor x\rfloorψ(x)}{\text G(x)}dx$$

Comment: What is the $\$$ in the title supposed to be?

Comment: @markvs your edit doesn't make sense

Comment: See the [**superfactorial $n\$$**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superfactorial.html). The notation literally has the dollar sign in it.

Comment: No, @tymagaidash, make your question self-contained. What is $G?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See the [Barnes G function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function). It also has links in the question

Comment: @markvs I didn't ask you about $G,$ I asked you why you edited the question to nonsense.

Comment: I have gotten rid of the notation just to be safe. Here is the original quote from the question as of edit $1$:” the [Barnes G](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function), [K](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-function), [Hyperfactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html), and [the Sloane and Plouffe version of the Superfactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superfactorial.html) functions”. I gave all necessary links albeit a bit compact.

Comment: I am glad this has been settled. Thanks for your feedback. Do you think I should still include the $n\$$ super factorial notation as it is related to the Barnes G function?

Comment: @BarryCipra That used to just mean:$$\sum_a^b f(n)=\sum_{n=a}^b f(n)$$ There is only one index, so I thought I could simplify the notation like in other posts.

Comment: What are the first two terms in your sum? If I interprest the empty product as $1$, the first term is  $${\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{- 1} {\frac{1}{{k!}}} } =1
$$ and the second is $1/0!=1$. But in your other notation $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1!2! \cdots (n - 1)!}}} 
$$ the first term seems to be $1/(-1)!=0$ and the second is again $1/0!=1$. Could you please clarify this? It is porbably better to start the summation from $n=2$ and separate the terms corresponding to $n=0,1$.

Comment: @Gary Please see [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod_%28k%3D0%29%5E%28n-2%29%281%2F+k%21+%29). The negative terms are just 1, so you can set $k$ to start at a slightly higher value.

Comment: Let me edit this in. When I finish, then I will say so.

Comment: Another question. What is $q$ in the conjectured closed form expression in terms of ${}_1 \tilde{F}_q$?

Comment: @Gary That is why I asked the question. There is an “$n-1$” amount of factorials in the sum denominator, so I am not sure. For example, when $q=3$, we already have $4+$ digits of precision: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\text G(n)}≈3+\,_1\rm{\tilde F}_3(1;-2,-1,0;1)=3+\frac{\,_0\rm F_2(2,3;1)}2= 3.5868639104823…$$ but this is not the exact answer, just an approximation.

Comment: @Gary I have realized that $\text G(x),x=1,2,3$ all give 1, so we can extract them and have no gamma function issues. Could you please check if there are any typos? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: When you extract out the first three Barnes-$G$ terms, they should remain reciprocals to stay consistent (I know $1/1=1$ but still).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131168/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-gary).

Comment: @Gary The goal is to evaluate/simplify  the sum and not write it out,  $\ $but I see your point. Do you have any ideas on how to simplify the result?