# How many bijections $ \pi: \{1,2, \dots,n \} \to \{1,2, \dots,n \} $ are there such that $ \pi(j) \neq j $?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, derangements

Let $n \in \mathbb{N} $. How many bijections $ \pi: \{1,2, \dots,n \} \to \{1,2, \dots,n \} $ are there such that $ \pi(j) \neq j $, for all $j \in \{1,2, \dots,n \} $?

My solution is quite simple:

$$ \pi(1)\in \{2, \dots,n \}  \\ \pi(2)\in \{1, \dots,n \} \backslash \{\pi(1) \} \\ \dots \\
\pi(n)\in \{1,2, \dots,n-1 \} \backslash \{\pi(1), \dots, \pi(n-1) \} $$

So if $ \Pi = \{ \pi \} $, then $ | \Pi | = (n-1)! $

This doesn't add up with the answer though, and I don't know whats wrong with my approach. Whats wrong?

[image: Here's the solution]

Comment: Cf. [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement); this question seems more [tag:combinatorics] than [tag:elementary-number-theory]

Comment: Note: We don't have $\pi(2)\in\{1,\dots, n\}\setminus\{\pi(1)\}$, but $$\pi(2)\in\{1,\dots, n\}\setminus\{2,\pi(1)\}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a problem understanding the proof of Rencontres numbers (Derangements)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/i-have-a-problem-understanding-the-proof-of-rencontres-numbers-derangements)

Comment: As for your mistake and what was wrong with your approach, @MaximilianJanisch hit the nail on the head.  The punchline is that to utilize rule of product it must be the case that *regardless* what earlier choices were made the number of available choices for a particular step must be consistent.  Here, if you choose $\pi(1)=2$ in the first step then you have $n-1$ choices for what $\pi(2)$ could be, however if you were to instead have chosen $\pi(1)=3$ or anything else you would instead have $n-2$ choices for what $\pi(2)$ could be as it could neither be $\pi(1)$ nor could it be $2$.

Comment: I see, thanks! But according to the solution, $ | A | \geq (n-1)! $, right? So it's more than just permutations that move all elements

Comment: There was a slight error in what @JMoravitz said too: The number of permutations with $\pi(1)\neq 1$ is $n! - (n-1)!$ . The number of derangements $|A|$, which is the sum in your solution, actually happens to be the nearest integer to $\frac{n!}e$, which is less than $n!- (n-1)!$

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.  I'll delete that bit