# Probability that at least one ball having the number on it as the round it was picked?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question goes: You have n balls in a hat with each having a number 1,2,3..n on it, and you blindly pick a ball without replacement, picking one ball in each of n rounds.  what is the probability that at least one ball has the same number as the round it was picked in?

I am not trying to make you make my assignment, since this is actually for practise. I just have a hard time figuring out how to calculate it, so I could use some help

Comment: See [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#:~:text=In%20combinatorial%20mathematics%2C%20a%20derangement,that%20has%20no%20fixed%20points.)

Comment: It is easier to find the probability that none match.  See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/i-have-a-problem-understanding-the-proof-of-rencontres-numbers-derangements