# Finding the probability of an event by using the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: probability

Given the set $\Omega$ containing the permutations of the numbers $\{1,2,...,N\}$, we consider the uniform distribution $\mathbb{P}$, so that the probability of an elementary event, i.e. the probability of drawing an arbitrary permutation will be $\mathbb{P}({\sigma}) = 1/N!.$ A fixed point of a permutation $\sigma$ is a number $i\in \{ 1,2,...,N \}, \sigma(i) = i.$ I would like to find the probability to draw at random a permutation containing $k, 0\leq k \leq N,$ fixed points by using the inclusion-exclusion principle, $$\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1}^n S_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \sum_{1\leq i_1 < \dots <i_k\leq n} \mathbb{P} (S_{i_1} \cap \dots \cap S_{i_k}).$$ The number of permutations with $k$ fixed points is $C_k^N = \frac{N!}{k!(N-k)!},$ so that the probability of getting at random a permutation with $k$ fixed points will be $\frac{C_k^N}{N!} = \frac{1}{k!(N-k)!}.$ Is this correct ? How can I find this by using the inclusion-exclusion principle ? I thought about the following: one needs to divide the set of permutations containing $k$ fixed points into not necessarily disjoint subsets. For example one way would be to consider the permutations (with $k$ fixed points) which contain $1$ as a fixed point all over to permutations which contain $N$ as a fixed point. I do not know how to go from here. Do you have any suggestion or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: First, you should get familiar with understanding [derangements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/i-have-a-problem-understanding-the-proof-of-rencontres-numbers-derangements) and how inclusion-exclusion is used for that.  With this as a foundation, and denoting the number of derangements of $m$ elements as $!m$, the answer to your question of the probability of $k$ fixed points when looking at a random permutation of $N$ elements will be $\dfrac{\binom{N}{k}\cdot !(N-k)}{N!}$, seen by choosing the fixed points and then choosing a derangement of the rest.

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand why my result deviates from this one. But I am unfamiliar with the subject of derangements.

Comment: As to your attempt, you say "*The number of permutations with $k$ fixed points is $\binom{N}{k}$*"  This is inaccurate for a number of reasons.  That is merely the number of ways of selecting $k$ points to fix in place, but you still need to consider the number of ways in which the remaining $N-k$ points can be arranged.  You might be inclined to say that you have $(N-k)!$ ways to arrange them, but in some of those you will have additional fixed points.

Comment: The punchline (*as explained in the linked post*) is for those $N-k$ remaining elements, consider "The first is not assigned to itself *and* the second is not assigned to itself *and* ..." as the complement of "The first is assigned to itself *or* the second is assigned to itself *or* ..." and run inclusion-exclusion on that.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the mistake. But I am still not able to use the inclusion-exclusion principle to find the same result.

Comment: Without more information, I can not tell you what you are doing wrong or missing.  I can only emphasize that the linked post (*and the many other posts linked to that post*) already contains many details on how to calculate derangements by many methods, including inclusion exclusion, and that my writing as $!(N-k)$ is shorthand for the final result rather than the expression that would have come about from inclusion-exclusion, having been $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-k} (-1)^i\binom{N-k}{i}(N-k-i)!$ or similar (*in case I made a typo*).  The shorthand is far easier to read and write.

Comment: What is the meaning of this phrase from the link, " Then the number of permutations in $k$
 of the $S_i$
 would be the number of permutations that fix $k$
 items."? Also, when I say inclusion-exclusion principle, I mean the expression I have posted in my question. Following the link, I can not see how such a principle is used there. I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: The sentence right before that one says $S_i$ is how they are labeling the set of permutations who fixed element $i$.  If a permutation is an element of exactly $5$ of these $S_i$ then it must be a permutation who fixed exactly five elements.  Similarly if we use an arbitrary number $k$.  "*When I say inclusion-exclusion I mean the expression...*" It appears in the very next line... just where we don't use $\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\leq n}$ since its not necessary since all ways of choosing $k$ indices result in the same count.  We got to replace that ugly sum with $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: Where does the factor $(-1)^{k-1}$ come from in the link ? May I assume that $S_i$ in the link contains a single fixed element, the element i, (this is not stated clearly in the link) ?

Comment: The powers of $-1$ come from using inclusion-exclusion.  The $S_i$ will certainly fix element $i$ but may fix more than just that.