Closed form of the recursion $D_{n+1} = n(D_n + D_{n-1})$
I got this problem from chapter five of Titu Andreescu A path to combinatorics for undergraduates. I'm asked to give a closed form to the given recursion given that $D_1 = 0$ and $D_2 = 1$. And I know that this closed form is $D_n = n!\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ which can be proven by using inclusion exclusion, however I'm interested in a solution based purely on recursions given that in the same chapter the following theorem is provided:
Let $z \neq 0$ a complex number. Then $f(n) = z^n$ satisfies $f(n)-a_1f(n-1)- \dots - a_kf(n-k) = 0$ for real constants $a_1 \dots a_k$ if and only if $z$ is root of $x^k- a_1x^{k-1}- \dots -a_k = 0$.
I know that this theorem cannot be used to solve this because in the recursion I gave the coefficients are not constant, but that's the kind of strategy I was looking to use. Any help would be appreciated.

'I'm interested in a solution based purely on recursion': do you mean you want àn inductive proof of the closed form you already know? If so, what stops you ?

No, I didin't meant an inductive proof. The exercise as such was to find a closed form to the given recursion. I just happen to know from later on the book that the closed form is the one I gave, but that one is proved by a method not yet discussed on the chapter in which this problem is.

The issue with your question is that you are asking us to provide a solution under restrictions that would only be evident to those who have read the book, because you provide no details about what you mean beyond "a solution based purely on recursions." What is likely to happen is that people will either provide answers based on whatever techniques they consider most convenient, or attempt to guess at the unstated restrictions. Either way, it is a waste of their time to do this, and for this reason, you should provide a clear set of criteria by which you want your question to be answered.

This older Q&A has a lot of good discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83472/137524

The sequence $x_n:=\frac{D_n}{n!}$ satisfies $x_1=0$, $x_2=\frac12$, and
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=-\frac1{n+1}(x_n-x_{n-1}),$$
i.e. $x_1=0$ and
$$x_n-x_{n-1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!},$$
i.e.
$$x_n =\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

By the way, there is a related theorem which says that if you have a sequence which satisfies a recurrence where the coefficients are polynomials in $n$, then the EGF satisfies a differential equation where the coefficients are polynomials in $x$.
To see how this all connects, consider the two operations:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sum a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum a_{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n!} \text{ and } x \sum a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum n a_{n - 1} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
See if you just have the derivative operator then you can shift the coefficients and so a recurrence like $f_{n + 2} = f_{n + 1} + f_{n}$ translates to a differential equation $y'' = y' + y$ (each shift corresponds to a derivative).
If we have coefficients which are in terms of $n$, then we can create these by multiplying by $x$. So in your case
$$
D_{n + 1} = nD_n + nD_{n-1} \text{ translates to } y' = xy' + xy.
$$
This is a homogeneous linear differential equation:
$$
\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{x}{1-x} \implies \log y = -x - \log(1-x) \implies y = \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}.
$$
And this is of course the EGF for the derangements problem. You can now use another common identity which just comes from multiplying $e^{-x}$ by $\frac1{1 - x}$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1 - x} e^{-x} &= \sum_i x^i \cdot \sum_j \frac{(-1)^j x^j}{j!} \\
&= \sum_n \left( \sum_{i + j = n} \frac{(-1)^j}{j!} \right) x^n  \\
&= \sum_n \left( n! \sum_{i + j = n} \frac{(-1)^j}{j!} \right) \frac{x^n}{n!}.
\end{align}
This gives us the formula
$$
D_n = n! \sum_{j = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^j}{j!}.
$$

This method is reversible too! If $y = \frac{e^{-x}}{1 - x}$ then (using the product rule on $e^{-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - x}$)
$$
y' = -\frac{e^{-x}}{1 - x} + \frac{e^{-x}}{(1 - x)^2} = -y + \frac{y}{1 - x}.
$$
And that rearranges back to $y' = xy' + xy$ which corresponds to $D_{n + 1} = nD_n + nD_{n - 1}$.
